# Esoteric languages thread

Tags: discussion, specific-question, moderation

Why was the [esoteric languages thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187715/) locked? Obviously there was controversy about whether or not the name of a certain famous esoteric language should be sanitized or not but to the best of my knowledge everyone was having a good time with the thread and sharing some cool programming-related oddities.

Comment: I think it was put in 'timeout'.

Answer (score 3):

We've been having issues with [Brianfudge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24079/is-the-language-brainfck-offensive) lately. A vampire [came to the conclusion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24079/is-the-language-brainfck-offensive/24206#24206) that **bad words** must be censored because some corporations use content filtering and, as we all learned in school, two wrongs make a right.

Comment: No, that's three lefts.  Two wrongs make money.

Comment: 2 Wrights make an airplane

Comment: @Dinah: What do two airplanes make?

Comment: @Pesto: If they love each other very much, a little airplane.

Comment: @Pesto: shhh, we do not speak of airplanes in pairs this close to 9/11.

Comment: I wonder how many people flagged belgariontheking's comment as offensive.

Answer (score 3):

There was [a bit of an edit war](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/187715/list) and the Mighty Lizard stepped in and put an end to it, because he does not f_ck around.

Answer (score 2):

[`bf`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) got added to the question Dec 23 2008. (fully written out ).
Sep 30 2009: it got re-written to block out the f word.

Then it got rolled back between those two versions half a dozen times.

Bill finally stepped in and locked it.

The interesting thing is that besides the edit Bill did, only one user edited the post to remove the f word.

Comment: I find it very interesting that it has been there spelled out *for almost a year*! And all of a sudden it is deemed *offensive*... and now it stays censored while I have the impression that most of the community doesn't want that. WTF?

Comment: @fretje - Most of the community doesn't like it, but most are willing to accept it because it risks tickling Websense and other web-blocking software used by schools or businesses. I philosophically disagree with this strategy of appeasement, but Stack Overflow is a mostly benevolent dictatorship, so I don't have a say in the matter.

Comment: @Chris: Still makes no sense... What I also said to Jeff Atwood in the comments on this answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24079/is-the-language-brainfck-offensive/24206#24206: "I don't understand how this "corporate net filtering" thing you talk about would be a problem for this site, while it isn't a problem for Wikipedia."

Answer (score 1):

It seemed pretty self-explanatory at the time, but since I forgot about it and let a day go by before unlocking it, I can see how that's no longer the case.  I was alerted to an edit/rollback war in progress and decided the question and one of the answers needed a cool off period.  Thanks for reminding me about it.  It's unlocked now.

Comment: Excellent. Let the edit war resume!

Comment: @Jon B: Even as I wrote that, I had a feeling that someone would take it as a "Game On!" declaration. :)

Comment: Despite the edit war people, thanks for re-opening the thread. I think the vast majority of the readers and contributors were enjoying it for its face-value.

Answer (score 0):

The moderator stepped in to stop the edit wars over m_nging of obscene terms.
See this [link.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24079/is-the-language-brainfck-offensive/24082#24082)

Comment: @W_lboug: you're just jealous that you'll never beat Lance's -15 record.

Comment: @Jon B: Pfft. I could if I wanted to.

Comment: I have absolutely no doubt of that in my mind.