# What are FML and BWSS?

Tags: discussion, support, advertising

I see this ad sometimes and I would like to know what the acronyms are.

[image]

Comment: I don't know about the first word but I assumed the second word was "bliss".

Comment: It's not using any acronyms

Comment: Are you saying that FML is not an acronym?

Comment: Pronounce FML as a word

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it... tried fml and ffffffffffmmmmmmmmmmmmmlllllllllll... Could you translate?

Comment: Urban dictionary ftw. http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=fml

Comment: Did anyone else think Bliss was BWSS? I spent a few minutes Googling some crazy acronym

Comment: @random: I can't find any evidence that FML is any less of an acronym than NATO is. Have a look at [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acronym_and_initialism#Comparing_a_few_examples_of_each_type).

Comment: That whole Wikipedia article explains the difference between acronyms and initialisms @okt

Comment: Actually, it explains that there doesn't appear to be a fixed definition of an acronym. @random

Comment: I thought it was BWSS too.  If it didn't mean anything before, it will now.  ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The second looks like the word "bliss" to me (i.e. not an acronym), and the first is probably an acronym for ["f*** my life"](http://www.fmylife.com/).

Comment: Wow... not exactly professional, is it?

Comment: @Robert, I like it.  No need to be perfectly professional all the time.

Comment: @jinguy: I like it too, it's just a bit... startling for a careers ad, now that I know what it actually means.  Perhaps that was the intended effect.

Comment: The first time I saw it I thought the slider was interactive and tried to fiddle around with it...

Comment: Same thing happened to me.

Comment: @Time http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29931/what-is-the-rationale-behind-the-no-cursing-rule/29950#29950

Answer (score 1):

The first is most definitely an acronym for 'F*ck My Life'.  And the second is the word 'Bliss'.  They are essentially two opposite ends of the job satisfaction spectrum.