# Could there be a self-edit threshold that precludes a question from getting on the HNQ list?

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions

I had to check out [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/100356/do-these-ten-reasons-prove-that-the-trinity-doctrine-is-blasphemous) this morning in my moderatorial duties, and I was a little grieved to see it hit the HNQ at some point after it was asked, but certainly after the OP had edited it several times, it made it to the queue.

I'm sure there's still a lot of good questions that get self-edited, but since there's obviously some sort of magic algorithm involved, it stands to reason that 3-5 self-edits is a tiny yellow flag if 20+ self-edits is red flag.

Comment: Just lock the question, and it should prevent it from being in HNQ. It not, feature request should be posted, and until then, question can be closed as non-elegant solution. (I'm pretty sure closed questions are excluded right away from HNQ.)

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda we'd have to be paying pretty close attention to do that

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the problem, because the post on Christianity Q&A doesn't seem to be a question, is more like a set of affirmations constructed perhaps to provoke (I'm not sure how Christians view these kinds of affirmations). But since it's essentially not a question, the post should be closed pending edits and the author instructed on the functioning and rules of the site.

Comment: Do you have an rss feed setup for HNQ questions for your site in a chat room? https://lackadaisical-appeal.glitch.me/  (I'm the author of that app)

Comment: @rene yeah, we've got that set up.  Maybe I read the history wrong and it never hit the HNQ after all.  Another mod just prevented it from getting on.  I guess this feature request still stands as though - there were already 10 edits, seems like that should be reason enough to prevent a question from getting on HNQ, but maybe it is already

Comment: @AugustoVasques yeah, it's an admittedly terrible question - I'll probably close it in a few minutes.

Comment: As far as I know, even after the [last round of rework on the HNQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325060/369802), the formula as described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61343/369802) stayed the same, and it does not count edits at all. I also only see a 'remove from hot network questions' entry in the timeline, so it looks like it never actually hit the HNQ? It *is* possible to use that button [pre-emptively](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372457/369802), so I wonder if that's perhaps what happened here (or was it kicked out so fast it didn't even register on the timeline?)

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda Moderators have a specific option to remove a question from the HNQ list. It's not necessary for moderators to perform some other action which has removal from the HNQ as a secondary effect. This has been the case for quite some time. The post linked by Tinkeringbell (above as "pre-emptively") has an image of what the mod popup looks like.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell yeah, I'm thinking the other mod did it pre-emptively, but even so it got me thinking that it should be a "question smell" worthy of excluding from the HNQ if it's not in there already (as it appears to not be)

Comment: @Makyen I see, so yeah, in those rare cases of too many edits that turns the question into something else, or just trolling, mod can manually remove it from HNQ if it got there somehow.