# Very hot network questions found

Tags: bug, status-completed, hot-questions, timeline

The Boardgames Stack Exchange question [How would an instant or sorcery with an effect that targets work with Feather?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/47157/12315) became a Hot Network Question three times, according to its [timeline](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/posts/47157/timeline):

[image: timeline showing three 'became hot network question' events]

All three events have the exact timestamp (19:14:39 UTC - shown when you click the 'toggle format' link or upon hovering) so it's probably a race condition or something.

It's not a unique case; [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1043063/very-hot-questions) finds instances on a single site, and [this cross-site query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1063399/hottest-questions-networkwide) lists all occurrences in the network (currently 448). The current record holders, with 44 HNQ entry events, are

- [Was it ever possible to access the full EGA color space in 200-line modes?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/15935/3748) on Retrocomputing
- [Using frozen light as a starship shield](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/178041/8732) on Worldbuilding

[image]

Comment: It could be that the question dropped on and off the list, but I didn't think that this was supposed to leave an entry (see [the announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325060/323179)).

Comment: @Laurel Nah, that only happens every 15 minutes, so it'd have different time stamps. These are all the same. It's more obvious if you "toggle format" to get the precise time rather than the relative time. The thing I find curious is that they aren't considered simultaneous.

Comment: I wonder if [three events](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60756/how-do-the-arbitrary-hotness-points-work-on-the-new-stack-exchange-home-page-a) could have sequentially checked if it was on the list and seeing that it wasn't checked for the particular tested attribute, seeing that the condition had been met it added it and fired off a message, a rare occurance? - is there a SEDE query to check for superheated HNQs? (is that how this was discovered).

Comment: [Same thing here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/83759/revisions), but just twice. Maybe the bug is on its way to being fixed (thrice to twice)?

Comment: Few more examples [1](https://writing.stackexchange.com/posts/45869/timeline), [2](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/442792/timeline)

Comment: Another example [with 23 occurrences](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/244185/timeline) within three seconds

Comment: We got one with 25 occurrences: https://data.stackexchange.com/materials/query/1232023/entered-hnq-more-than-once#resultSets

Comment: [43 occurrences](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1252648/timeline) in four seconds.

Comment: This one had [15 occurrences](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/258164/timeline) over a period of 4 seconds.

Comment: @Adam just curious, where does this bug sit in the priority list of bugs?:)

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask Perhaps it's too hot to touch

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask Very low since it doesn't appear to affect actual functionality.

Comment: @AdamLear sure, but it clutters the timeline and doesn't look good. :/

Comment: SciFi question w/ 26 occurrenceS: https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13136/a-question-was-chosen-as-a-hot-network-question-simultaneously-26-times-accordi - perhaps the priority should be upped a notch since it is clearly happening with some frequency still and is happening network wide, functionality aside...

Comment: @AdamLear Can we at least please get an answer that explains the cause of the bug?

Comment: @SonictheMaskedWerehog: My wild guess is that this is some combination of eventual consistency and "It always worked that way, but nobody could see it until now."

Comment: @SonictheMaskedWerehog Well if we knew the cause of the bug, we'd fix the bug. :P

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The underlying issue here has (hopefully) been fixed. Extra post history entries have been removed.

The cause was a race condition on the hot network questions global cache:

1. We cache Hot Network Questions (HNQ) across the entire network. The cache expires every 15 minutes. Every pageload (on every site) that shows HNQ hits this cache.
2. As soon as the cache expires — at `T1` —, the next request across the network will recalc the HNQ list and recache it in the global cache. This executes extremely quickly (normally in around 10-15 ms), and is completed at `T4`.
3. If multiple requests come through between `T1` and `T4`, then each of these requests would calculate a new HNQ list (with the last one being completed being the one to be saved in the global cache).

   1. This is not an issue for the performance of the HNQ. Worst case scenario is that a few extra individual pageloads somewhere on the network took an extra 10ms to load.
   2. In the case when a post is returned in the list that is on HNQ for the first time (and thus does not yet have a `PostHistory` entry for "became hot network question"), then each of the multiple requests will attempt to add this `PostHistory` entry.
   3. When adding the entry (on any of the requests), we first query for all new HNQ posts (`T2`) on the given site that dont have the `PostHistory` entry, and then add the entry (`T3`).
4. If there are multiple requests (between `T1` and `T4`) picking up a new HNQ post where at `T2` for the request no other request had hit `T3` (at which point a `PostHistory` entry would be recorded for the post and any subsequent requests initiated before `T4` would pick them up at `T2`), then each one will record a `PostHistory` entry, leading to what was reported above (where the three `PostHistory` records where recorded from requests that occurred at `19:14:39.453`, `19:14:39.457`, `19:14:39.463`).

The fix:

- Change the logic of the `PostHistory` insert from EF to an [`If not exists...insert` query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20971775/51). This eliminates the lag between `T2` and `min(T3)` as the cause of the duplicate entry race condition here, as the existance check occurs during the insert request.
- There is a chance that this will not completely eliminate the issue under high load, and we may need to add an [`UPDLOCK` hint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3791506/51) to the query as well. Decided to go incrementally with this, and will add the lock later if needed.
- The old duplicate history entries have been removed.

---

> new HNQ post
> concurrent requests hit cache
> check hist, avoid race

Comment: I appreciate the detailed clarification of the issue and the fix (and the haiku). I'll accept once I have seen the results :)

Comment: Just to be thorough, will this also fix [this issue](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13136/a-question-was-chosen-as-a-hot-network-question-simultaneously-26-times-accordi)?

Comment: An "SQL Server Application lock" may be better then UPDLOCK hint, maybe protecting the update of the cache as well.

Comment: Or make the transaction serializable.

Comment: FWIW I just observed [double removal from HNQ](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3848544/timeline), guess history check isn't performed at requests for removal

Comment: Looks like it resurfaced: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362207/392799

Comment: ...and [resurfaced again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387901/multiple-became-hot-network-question-events-on-timeline?noredirect=1) today