# Triple HNQ entry (2022 edition)

Tags: bug, hot-questions, timeline

[This question appears to have entered the HNQ list **three times** with the same timestamp](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/270554/timeline):

[image: "became hot network question" x3]

Seemingly related to [Very hot network questions found](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327889/278659), but not a duplicate because that was marked as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) back in 2020.

Comment: FYI, [ymb1's comment](/questions/327889/very-hot-network-questions-found#comment1208211_354731) to [Yaakov Ellis' answer](/a/354731) there links to the more recent [How hot? Double hot (bug resurfaced?)](/q/362207).

Comment: If anything, it doesn't have an effect on the HNQ feed it seems https://lackadaisical-appeal.glitch.me/hnq/=scifi.stackexchange.com

Comment: I knew which question it was :3

Comment: Well, Yaakov did say it was *hopefully* fixed so no lies were told. Race conditions are impossible to fix, even for excellent developers like Yaakov. He can add patches, but it won't fix the real bug.

Comment: Ahh that's hot, [that's hot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/271505/revisions). (recent occurrence)