# Multiple "became hot network question" events on timeline

Tags: bug, hot-questions, timeline

The [timeline for this question on literature.se](https://literature.stackexchange.com/posts/24444/timeline) shows multiple "became hot network question" events (see screenshot below). This looks like a bug.

[image: Screenshot of timeline view showing table of events. There are six events, four of which have the description "history—became hot network question" and the other two are "answer—added" and "history—asked"]

Comment: Hmm. That has [happened before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327889/369802) but was supposedly fixed...

Comment: @Tinkeringbell It's an ongoing regression of that bug; see above.

Comment: @Sonic well sadly no staff or mod deem that regression as important enough to mark it as status review, the bug is there to stay. :(