Please add an event for when a question is removed from the HNQ
Currently, when a question is added to the HNQ (Hot Network Questions), an event is created in the post's history. However (unless it was manually removed by a moderator), no event exists for when a question is removed from the HNQ (example).
I don't know if this would be a problem, but questions could repeatedly drop on and off the HNQ list, flooding the post's history. I'd imagine that this could be solved by deleting the event if the question is placed back on the HNQ within a set amount of time, maybe of few hours or a day or something.
Could this be implemented?

Some of us have wanted this ever since HNQ events first got added to the timeline. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325060/334566 But I guess there's no harm in asking again...
