# What do you get if you cross a wiki and a forum?

Tags: discussion, wording

***What do you get if you cross two different concepts?*** Isn't it a big risk that we create enormous confusion?

A lot of people come in with the picture of a phpBB system where you use "I" a lot. But then when you actually write the question, you have to twist your brain to accept that it should be "we", because then it's a wiki. Then you have invested a lot of time and you also discover that the question was asked before. Do you really think anyone will delete the question then? No, of course not. He/she fill fight for it to survive.

This twist is not understood by newcomers and is the reason that we all hate each other back at Stackoverflow.

The most effective method to destroy a community is do dive into it and make people angry at each other. I think SO fits that description like a hand in a glove.

Do not be surprised if "stacks" all over the world will create angry people. Do not be surprised if the never ending "What's the right question?"-question will be the discussion for every meta site.

Should we change the wording to create better understanding? or Is the benefit better then the bad garbage(angry people)? What do you think? Or can we battle this problem with "[closed]"?

Right answer to my question is:  ***"Major confusion and angry people"***

Comment: may be related somehow with this - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31168/fk-you-fk-you-and-fk-you-whos-next/31173#31173

Comment: Cool! You got the RIGHT answer!

Comment: Well, if you cross a horse and a horn, what do you get?

Comment: @gnoupi: an equinophone? a flugelhorn? what? don't keep us in suspense, man!

Comment: @quack: Wrong! You get 40% of meta magic answers!

Comment: No offense, but I can't believe my suggestion for vote to cw is getting more downvotes than this. I must have really annoyed some people

Comment: @Casebash: Don't forget that votes on feature requests are mostly agree/disagree, while with votes on discussiony questions like this, all bets are off.

Comment: @Casebash - also, don't make everything about you, or compare other questions to yours. Just because people disagree with your proposition doesn't mean they have to act the same with everything else. Doesn't mean they are picking on you personally, as well. It only means they disagree with your proposition. You, as an individual person, are not really important, in such case.

Comment: @gnoupi: Maybe, maybe not. I actually don't care much about the idea, it's just that I'm trying to lie low for a while and avoid saying anything controversal, so I really don't like getting so much negative attention.

Comment: Also, I can't believe it's the worst idea ive had =P

Comment: @Casebash - I believe in you, you can have even worse ones =)

Answer (score 15):

> What do you get if you cross two different concepts? Isn't it a big risk that we create enormous confusion?

Yeah, remember the Telefax – writing through the telephone? Or the automobile – a horseless carriage? The Earth as a Sphere, but the Australians don't fall off? Chewing gum – you kinda eat it, but not really? And then beef jerkey – kinda like chewing gum, but you really do eat it, but it's not gum, it's meat? There's still some major confusion going on around these topics.

> A lot of people come in with the picture of a phpBB system where you use "I" a lot. But then when you actually write the question, you have to twist your brain to accept that it should be "we", because then it's a wiki.

Yes.

> Then you have invested a lot of time and you also discover that the question was asked before.

That's great – because you had a question, right? No need to wait until you get the answer. *It's already there!*

> Do you really think anyone will delete the question then?

They are not supposed to be deleted. They are supposed to be closed as a duplicate, but stick around, so people searching for similar questions with different wordings in the end all can find the single canonical answer to their question.

> No, of course not. He/she fill fight for it to survive.

"This is the Microsoft help desk, how can I help you?" – "Yeah, I just bought this new computer, and there's Windows on it, but I want to turn off the computer for now and I can't find a way to stop Windows." – "I'll be glad to help you, sir; we get this question a lot. You have to click on *St…*" – "What the &%$§ are you talking about? I'm not the first one who asks this? You already know the answer? Cut this crap right now! I demand you *forget the answer right now* and *re-find the solution!*"

> This twist is not understood by newcomers

Then start being helpful and explaining, instead of posting rants on Meta.

> and is the reason that we all hate each other back at Stackoverflow.

That would be news to me. Hey, here's a joke for lighting up a bit. Traffic radio: "Attention drivers, a vehicle is driving against the traffic on I-101." Driver: "What's he talking about, *a vehicle*? There are, like, hundreds!"

> The most effective method to destroy a community is do dive into it and make people angry at each other. I think SO fits that description like a hand in a glove.

Did it ever occur to you that the Stack Overflow community was *created* with this model of thinking? It's not like people were pulled away from their phpBBs and BBCodes and Smileys to be packed into this weird Wiki-Forum-Reddit-Thingadongdong. They were, in a sense, born into this way of doing things.

> Do not be surprised if "stacks" all over the world will create angry people. Do not be surprised if the never ending "What's the right question?"-question will be the discussion for every meta site.

It seems like you have been doing some in-depth analysis. Do you have a magic eight ball that says "We're all going to die!!!" on all sides?

> Should we change the wording to create better understanding?

So you want to change the *wording* although you claim the problem is in the *concept*? That's the "Patriot Act" way.

> or Is the benefit better then the bad garbage(angry people)?

Yes. At least I see quite some helpfulness on SO and very few fist fights.

> What do you think? Or can we battle this problem with "[closed]"?

You have failed to prove that there even *is* a problem.

> Right answer to my question is: "Major confusion and angry people"

Right answer to your question is: "What is your question?"

Comment: *clap clap clap*

Comment: Good answer, but was it really worth putting all that effort into ansering a troll?

Comment: @Casebash: I don't think the OP is trolling.

Comment: @balph: yeh, I am becoming too much of a pessimist

Comment: Looking at his previous question, this guy *is* a troll. Still, +1.

Comment: I think it's a never ending battle. Some chemicals don't fit together. You don't mix some colors. But on SO you even have a profile, but there is no space where you can communicate with others. You get a horrific feeling of being gaged. SO is not for people that like other people. Only for hard core geeks.

Comment: Labeled like a terrorist with "posting rants" is very common.. that is sad. It's like you must defend you cult. If you invest in stackoverflow you will defend it like your life is at stake. This is very interesting..

Comment: @user144819: First and foremost, SO is about *questions and answers*, not about people. Also, it's kind of unfair that you suggest I labeled you a "terrorist." I said nothing more than that your question is a rant. Which it is. We've all done that; me included. You might have noticed that I was actually defending you in the comments above. And finally: I don't know what kind of experience you've had on SO that makes you say these things, but please be aware that this doesn't mean *everyone*, or even the majority of users, has these experiences.

Answer (score 3):

> What do you get if you cross two
> different concepts?

I don't know about concepts, but if you cross a minotaur with a centaur you get a person.  <sub><sup>And/or a pony with a bull's head.  But I digress.</sup></sub>

### Discussatisfaction

(on conflicting requirements)

1. People searching for information do not want to swim through 17 pages of discussion to find the solution to their problem in a post on page 2 which was expanded in page 7. It is painful and is destroying the internet.
2. For some odd reason that I do not fully grok, people **LOVE** discussing stuff ad-infinitum. This conflicts with point 1. Need proof, look at meta.

SOs reputation/badges/wiki is one approach that can be used that focuses on long term usefulness as opposed to short term discussatisfaction.

Comment: For the reason for 2., see http://xkcd.com/386/

Comment: +1 for grok. I love grok. Grok, grok, grok.