# what is the policy on good questions with vulgar content?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are expletives allowed on SE sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-allowed-on-se-sites)
>   [What kind of idiot is Richard? - or: Expletives in answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58728/what-kind-of-idiot-is-richard-or-expletives-in-answers)

i would like to know if there is a policy (and i wasnt able to find any) on asking questions which are "good" - in the sense of the quality of the content and the quality of the question but contain vulgar words like this post:

[Trouble connecting to MySQL database using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527601/trouble-connecting-to-mysql-database-using-php)

im not exactly saying it's "good" otherwise, but it's just an example of a question however it contains vulgarities in it. do we keep it or do we close it?

Comment: Where is the profanity in that post?

Comment: they use the F-word

Comment: Um... no they don't.

Comment: Is "Fatal error" the f-word?

Comment: What "F" word? Fix?  Function?  Gasp... fatal?

Comment: @JeffMercado Flagging your comment for profanity

Comment: @jonsca: Oh FixFuntionFatal...

Comment: wow i cant believe he asked that question

Comment: `dbpass` should be read as `db pass`, not `dbp ass`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What kind of idiot is Richard? - or: Expletives in answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58728/what-kind-of-idiot-is-richard-or-expletives-in-answers), [Are expletives allowed on SE sites?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-allowed-on-se-sites), [Let's clean up low-quality posts with profanity on Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110682/lets-clean-up-low-quality-posts-with-profanity-on-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 3):

Vulgarities should be edited out of questions and answers.  That's why we give so many people that privilege.

In general posts with good content should always be kept around on the site.

Comment: What about [questions/answers with links containing offensive words](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8964804/css-issue-with-aligning-element-to-bottom)?

Comment: @netcoder In that case I'd hide the link in some test, which I'm about to do.  But the context is necessary.  Bad words are a necessary evil in cases like that I suppose.

Comment: @netcoder Check out my edit.  I think that's appropriate.

Comment: Yes, yes indeed.

Comment: But what about [posts that are *about* bad words](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6099598/398242)? ;)

Comment: @Madmartigan Ha, that's pretty interesting.  In that context the word isn't even being used in a vulgar way.