# It is a sad day on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

`not-programming-related` is no more

[shot of close reasons http://www.juanformoso.com.ar/images/so9.png](http://www.juanformoso.com.ar/images/so9.png)

Long live NPR!

Comment: I propose a Stack Overflow feature cemetery for those beloved features that once were among us but are no more. The addition of each feature would require a sad and dignified ceremony.

Comment: This image needs a black frame.

Comment: @pekka, added a black ribbon

Comment: Very good. ----

Comment: Oh, NPR... we hardly knew ye. Actually, we probably knew ye too well.

Comment: Me too. I miss the good old days of sifting through useless information!

Comment: -1 Whats your question.

Comment: @Dat: obviously your knowledge of the site is limited. Seeing your profiles I can see that you don't have enough rep yet for closing. This question talks about a closing reason that has been removed.

Comment: @voy, never mind him, he's stalking me; serial downvoting me and commenting in a lot of my posts. Luckily the protections in place for this kind of things work great!

Comment: @Dow: shhh! Se va a dar cuenta! No lo avives ;)

Comment: @voyager if you looked at my rep it should be obvious that Im new to the site and therefore yes my knowledge of the site is limited.  On the other hand your knowledge of an interrogative statement is severely lacking.

Comment: @dat could you at least not cast opinions about things that you don't know then? Your opinion of my knowledge of the English language is irrelevant to the matter at hand.

Comment: @dat what is obvious is that most of your comments seem to be wining about something, generally downvotes.

Comment: People whining about being downvoted are often unable to see why they're being downvoted. That is, they're posting junk and the community is correcting itself. @dat

Comment: @voy I have not cast any opinions without significant evidence of leading to me to believe otherwise.  For example, "This question talks about a closing reason that has been removed", you show me where the question is and I promise to retract my statement.

Comment: @ran and voy - If you believe that my genuine interest in bringing fundamental flaws @ META to light is whining... the yes, Im whining.  In regards to posting junk?  Ive had plenty of good posts here that had to be deleted in order to keep people from retaliating because they lack the ability to discuss a topic like an adult.  Bring up my profile and you will see that posts (months old) Im unable to delete are still being downvoted today because they have no other recourse.  Its things like that Im trying to expose to the Admins and if I need to fall on the sword, so be it.

Comment: @Dat: Maybe you should *first* question yourself *why* exactly those posts are down-voted in stead of exposing it to the "Admins" (they're called moderators around here and "exposing" something to them is easily done by "flagging").

Comment: @fre thank you but I know know they are down voted and flagging is only for noise offensive or spam, but I do appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: @Qui-Gon: There are three options for flagging a post, and one of them isn't for offensive or spam...

Comment: @mmyers did you do that math all by yourself?

Comment: @Qui: por que no te dejas de romper un poquito las pelotas pibe?
You have been spouting accusations, whining and insulting for the last two days, and you are *surprised* that people flag you offensive? **What is your problem?** If your questions were downvoted more than once, then it's because people didn't agree!

Comment: Its meta.. Relax and always bring your sense of humor.  Besides I dont think I have been anymore offensive than others have been to me.. Im just playing along.

Comment: @Qui-Gon: The key word being *relax*, I think. I don't insult people and they don't insult me (usually).
**Edit:** ...By the way, is your age correct in your SO profile? If you're really 12, then I'd suggest learning how to express your opinions without sounding like you're attacking people. If you're not really 12, then I'd suggest not acting as if you are.

Comment: Cmon.. you were offended by that?   Dont make me go though some of your banter with the other users...
Like I said, Im just playing with the community at large, heck earlier I was called an ignorant bottom-feeder that should go get them some waffles, and above your post I was called a little kid.  Pretty funny actually... but when I make a joke everyone gets all bent out of shape.  Sounds like you guys are good and dishing it out but not so good and receiving it.

Comment: @Qui-Gon (assuming you're talking to me): No, I wasn't offended; it's not that easy to offend me, and I try to keep it that way. I do needle people sometimes, but only users that I've been around a lot and whom I know can take it, like Welbog or gnovice or jjnguy.  If I post a comment and then realize it could be taken as genuinely insulting, or completely misunderstood by someone not familiar with the situation, I delete it. And I always keep it G-rated.

Comment: @mmyers Although you may keep it G-rated the community as a whole does not.  For example, would you consider this G-Rated http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24079/is-the-language-brainf-ck-offensive
I dont doubt you are an outstanding pilliar of this community (as I once tried to be: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42558/why-are-downvotes-different-on-meta/42559#42559 ) but the nicer I was the more serious I was and give my honest opinion on how to help the site, the more retaliation I received on meta and on other sites.  Now that Im joking around, funny thing my rep is going up.

Comment: @Qui-Gon Jinn: I never said I was an outstanding pillar of the community. :) Yes, retaliation should never be practiced -- but the only thing you can do about it once it starts is to flag things for moderator attention. And I don't see anyone saying inappropriate things in the answer you linked; Shog9 went a little over the top but then apologized. I don't think he's the type that would follow you around just to downvote you, anyway. (For what it's worth, I also disagree with several of your comments there.)

Comment: @mmyers to disagree is fine but..... well then we go back to the voting system and that would be off our topic. Im sure shog9 didnt but I can guarantee I could name 4 people who have.    moving on, you really cant flag a post as retaliation all you can do is bring it up to Jeff and a few points really isnt worthy of his attention.  Either way its obvious that many people are practicing this but nobody seems to care. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42716/contacting-a-moderator-closed

Comment: picture is gone...

Comment: Never post just the links, eventually, they all become obsolete or rot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am drinking a beer in its honour. May it rest in peace in Close Reason Heaven.

[image]
<sub>(source: [pekkagaiser.com](http://www.pekkagaiser.com/stuff/beer.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 11):

I'n a bit pissed off with this (no surprise there, I hear people mutter). Off topic (or OT , as we long-time Usenet users like to say it) is a very generic term.  A post can be off-topic because it is:

- subjective
- argumentative
- not a real question
- too localized
- etc. etc.

In other words, "not programming related" had a real meaning, "off topic" does not.

Comment: But those things aren't *actually* off topic. They're on-topic posts that fail in some other way. I can be on-topic but be subjective--you can say "that's not what we're talking about; we're talking about things that aren't that subjective", but it's not a shift of topic you're seeking. You're saying my question is irrelevant, which is synonymous with being OT, and is even commonly used as an *exact* synonym, but which it actually isn't.

Comment: @D_N If the rules of the place you are posting to say that posts must not be subjective, too localized etc. and you post a question that  is subjective, too localized etc. then in Usenet terms at least, you are OT.

Comment: +1: agree with this completely. 'off-topic' is too broad a term.

Comment: @Neil, I don't disagree. I just disagree that Usenet is normative.

Answer (score 3):

Awww, now we can't confuse people by saying something is NPR and having them wonder what the hell it has anything to do with [public radio](http://www.npr.org/).

I guess now when we say something is OT people will think it's overtime and we're telling them to [wrap it up](http://www.funnyordie.com/videos/6e25b12f81/wrap-it-up-box-from-greatestcommercialparodies).

Comment: Hmm, I think we can now confuse people *all the more* by saying that something is NPR.

Comment: The first time I saw OT (on a forum), I wondered what the Old Testament had to do with anything there.

Comment: @mmyers: There are quite a few questions I'd like to go OT on. Real fire and brimstone like! ;)

Comment: Nah. You want to go medieval. On their ass.

Comment: @Neil: I prefer to go *medireview* on the asses of others. ;)

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a popular answer, but I can see the redundancy in having a *"Not Programming Related"* and *"Off Topic"*. NPR specifically states that a question should relate to programming or software development. If it does not follow that guideline, then the question is, by default, OT.

Since I don't have access I didn't know that NPR was replaced with OT. However, I think OT is fine. I have seen plenty of comments that alert the OP that a question is NPR. You also have to consider that a question could mention programming in some fashion but not actually be programming related - simply off topic. In that case, NPR does not give a tidy feel to the closure.

Comment: I'm pretty sure "Off Topic" didn't exist before today; I think one replaced the other.

Comment: @mmyers: I guess I wouldn't have known that since I don't get access to those tools...

Comment: Well, it didn't

Comment: What does Old Testament have to do with StackOverflow?