# Why are people downvoting my question on Meta?

Tags: discussion, voting, down-votes, meta

On all of the other SOFU sites a downvote means *The question is unclear or not useful.*  However, here on meta, a downvote has become a sign of *I don't agree with the question, suggestion, feature request, bug, etc.* being described in the question.

- What does a downvote on Meta really mean?
- What other reasons do people downvote on Meta?
- Why is it okay for meta to redefine the meaning of the downvote?  The tooltips and instructions are all the same here on meta.

<sub>Note: I'm not saying I disagree with the practice, just curious.</sub>

Comment: I'm surprised this Q wasn't downvoted into oblivion by the usual "irony" squad :)

Comment: I'm converting this question to a sofaq so we can use it as a reference when people ask about downvotes on meta.

Comment: Awful practice, because it discourages people from asking questions that invite critical analysis. Not sure how it plays a positive role in the community building.

Comment: As I said before, this practice makes disagreeing with a proposition costly. It might be even impossible to use for new users who arguably have a voice too. It's a shame, really.

Comment: @Evgeny "Discourages" may be too strong a word for "You might lose some rep on meta".

Comment: @Daniel Is "Discourages" too strong a word for "You might lose functionality on meta".

Comment: @Qui-Gon Jinn I must admit I didn't understand your comment.

Comment: @Evgeny @MPelletier You could always create a "controversial" feature request as cw, if you just want to open a discussion but you're afraid of the downvotes.

Comment: @Daniel people who migrate an existing account from other site start with 100 rep that should give them the ability to downvote.  if they lose any rep, not only do they lose rep, but they will lose functionality (the ability to downvote)  I doubt anyone cares about a few points but when you restrict access, people start to get "Discouraged".   
If they create a CW, do the upvotes count too?  If not, whats the incentive?

Comment: @Qui-Gon-Jinn How hard is it to get 30 points on Meta? That would compensate as much as 15 downvotes on your posts.

Comment: @Daniel Thats something you would need to ask every new poster here on meta (ex MPelletier Evgeny).. oh wait they are already discouraged and not coming back.

Comment: @Qui-Gon Jinn: @MPelletier and @Evgeny don't seem very discouraged lately: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/139539?tab=reputationhistory#tab-top, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/130609?tab=reputationhistory#tab-top

Comment: @Daniel I wasnt speaking literally.

Comment: Related: [How does Meta Stack Exchange work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-does-meta-stack-exchange-work)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Because S[OFU] are Q&A sites. Meta is actually [a replacement for the UserVoice bug report/feature request site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1) (with a bit of discussion thrown in...). The rules are different because Meta is... *kinda* misusing the SO engine.

And it's ok because we really do need a bug report / feature request / meta discussion site.

BTW: to the best of my knowledge, no one officially "changed" the meaning of a down-vote. Everyone has their own reasons for voting, it's a private matter, and you might well never know why you received an up- or down- vote unless they felt like telling you. The fact is, posts are allowed on Meta that normally aren't allowed on any of the other sites, and as a result you see voting behaviors that are rare elsewhere (but *not* unknown: check out votes on some of the more subjective posts on SO...)

Comment: We are above the SOFU rules, we are META

Comment: @downvoter - Above? Wrong direction buddy.  Meta is the gutter, the runoff, nay, *the very effluent* of stackoverflow.  Nasty, but necessary...

Comment: Although, in the meta question that was referenced, he Jeff says "It seems that questions tagged "bug" or "feature" could be voted on and commented in a fashion very similar to what uservoice already offers."  This implies that questions tagged with anything other than those (or feature-request given its more current popularity) should utilize the normal SO voting standards.

Comment: assuming this is correct, then maintaining a reputation score on META is moot.  Downvoting discourages new ideas and thinking out of the box for fear your ideas arent popular and we digress right back to HS (Im a popular kid with great ideas and youre not).   Its a great method on the other sites, but just doesnt work here.

Comment: @DataPimp makes a good point.

Comment: @Nick: Yeah, but that was a long time ago... habits have changed since then. Maybe a [feature-request] to update the text of the tooltips would be in order? It might already have been suggested though.

Comment: @DataPimp: what are you talking about? You realize that you don't actually lose anything tangible when your idea is down-voted, right? If your beef with down-voting is that you can't handle being told that folks don't care for your ideas, then voting isn't really the start of your problems...

Comment: @Shog9 C'mon was that really necessary? You have quite a bit of clout here and talking down to someone like that really is beneath you. Moving forward, you are missing my point, its not the downvote or even people that disagree with me. Its that they are tracked, whats the point? I also assume this is why people tend to side with (via comments or answers) Jeff or Jon because they know mass up votes will follow.

Comment: @DataPimp: besides, if loosing rep through downvotes is such a big problem for you, then you could use CW...

Comment: @voyager if I was worried about loosing rep, do you think I would be here siding with the minority?

Comment: What is this 'loosing rep'? rep wants to be free? or easy?

Comment: @DataPimp: was it *necessary* to call out a bogus theory? I thought so; was it *necessary* to essentially call us children for expressing our opinions? As for tracking reputation, I think most of us realize that it's fairly meaningless *even on S[OFU]!* The sites themselves use it as a rough measure of "trust" (participation, really) for controlling access to advanced tools, and beyond that it's just a game.

Comment: @shog9 If you believe I "essentially" called you a child, then I apologize, I will tread lighter.  Personally, I dont look at how trustworthy someone perceives me as meaningless, but if you do, how about you share a few thousand rep points (ie bounty) my way?  Put up or shut up.

Comment: @DataPimp: and sorry if I came off a bit rough; I'm having a discussion elsewhere with someone who is being intentionally obtuse in what appears to be a misguided effort to avoid real discussion - if that's coming through here as well, I sincerely apologize. As for trustworthiness / rep... Post something I like, and I'll up-vote it: that's how the site usually works after all. ;-)

Comment: @DataPimp: you need 5 downvotes to erase the rep given by a single upvote. If your ideas get more than 5 times the downvotes of the upvotes then maybe you shouldn't gain rep

Comment: @Kop by that rational, people who usually dont have good ideas will never have one and therefore should not be entitled to an opinion.  Where are you from, North Korea?

Comment: @DataPimp: check this out: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=[feature-request]%20user%3a135854&tab=newest
*Terribly* unpopular feature requests... But he can still post, still make suggestions, and certainly still does. Voting is irrelevant as far as it concerns the ability of a user to continue contributing to the site at a basic level.

Comment: @shog very true, but can he downvote, can he edit a post or have access to any other tools?   Yes he can do things at a basic level but do you think hes happy with that?  It looks to me that the guy really cares and is providing what he believes to be good suggestions and for this, for all his time and his efforts he is still considered a basic user.

Comment: @DataPimp: Well, this is what I was getting at originally: should you get a pat on the back for participation even when that participation is overwhelmingly negative (the "give him an A for Effort" school of thought), or should it take at least a little understanding of the workings and culture of the site you're suggesting be changed first?

Comment: @shog9 Why not both? like I said in my answer..A good post is a good post and should be rewarded. My opinion, is to add a small voting application the OP or MODs can include with the post so the meta users can separate the two.
the way the site is setup its easier to get additional access by simply siding with the majority than to formulate a real thought and suggest a new idea which might be beneficial to the community.

Comment: @DataPimp: And as I said in my answer, everyone has their own reasons for voting. If you want to up-vote folks who write good posts even when you disagree with their conclusions, go right ahead...

Comment: Im really not the type who will just do things "his way" because i think they are right.  Im going to follow the rules (actually I am but everyone else isnt ;) ) but at the same time tying to show the admins some fundamental flaws with the system while suggesting my thoughts on how it can be improved.  (Im sure its going to be similar to beating my head on an anvil and keep my rep below 100 but it is what it is)  have a good night sir.

Comment: @Shog9 I made some unpopular feature requests and some filter automatically banned my IP from posting questions on Meta anymore.  :-)  `Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more.`  If they're gonna use downvoting to mean 'I disagree', they have to disable that filter, or they're basically saying "don't post potentially unpopular ideas."

Answer (score 5):

It's the way the users of the SO sites measure the popularity of a feature-request using the SO engine.  Jeff and the team [do searches](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37844/interesting-stackoverflow-searches/37846#37846) every now and then on feature-requests to help them determine what to implement next.

Answer (score 0):

> Why are people downvoting my question
>   on Meta?

Simple, no reference to unicorns or even better still unicorns eating waffles.

Comment: and no freehand circles.

Comment: You forgot to mention waffles eating unicorns!

Comment: While I do get, and like the joke it is not an answer.

Comment: @Belinda it was a valid answer back when it was posted.