# Does badges page deserve its own tab in the main navigation?

Tags: discussion, badges

Is there hard data suggesting that it's a good idea to keep the badges tab in the main navigation bar?

How often is it visited? May that content go to "faq"?

I agree that badges make a difference in Q&A communities, but one less tab will simplify navigation... No?

What do you think?

Comment: why downvote :) is this a bad question? I am curious to know some opinions.

Comment: @Evgeny - as well as signifying a bad post, down-votes on meta are used by people to show disagreement with the proposal

Comment: @Chris there ya go :)

Comment: Badges?  *Badges!*  We don't *need no stinkin' badges!*

Comment: Look @Chris - I've just asked a question. It is not a proposal. Moreover - not a proposal to remove badges - which most people like. Don't you think that by giving downvotes for valid questions you are creating kind of a bad karma in the community?

Comment: @Evgeny - Re: Downvoting on Meta. Please review the following questions: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=why+are+people+downvoting+on+meta

Comment: Here's a particularly good one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42558/why-are-downvotes-different-on-meta

Comment: @Polyanna I don't think I will be asking more questions on this site. Thanks.

Comment: @Evgeny - I'm sorry to hear that.  We're not a *totally* bad bunch of people, but I fear we are not palatable to everybody.

Comment: Go with keela, you bosh'tet!

Comment: Another satisfied customer!

Comment: hey @Wel'Bog - what does that mean :)?

Comment: @Evgeny: Play more Mass Effect 2 until you figure it out. d:-|

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I do not think there is enough "real" information on the badges page to warrant it's own tab. I mean it basically consists of a list of 10 things or so with "x 10" or similar after it. It'd be a waste in my opinion. Plus I think badges are basically moot anyway

Comment: I don't agree that badges are moot though - because many people like them and find them a major motivator.

Comment: i guess partly I've selected this answer out of the sense of opposition :), but I agree that "badges" page is static and mostly boring. Where would it go instead and how to link to that nevertheless important item - it's a different story.

Comment: I think badges are pointless.. It's my opinion.. I never try to get a certain badge unless it also comes with reputation..

Answer (score 2):

Where would you put that link?

It isn't obstructive, it doesn't unbalance the design, it's a *major* (for diminishing values of major) feature of the site, and it keeps the top of the site in a nice aesthetic balance.

Comment: well this is a good question. Regarding contributing to "aesthetic balance" I'd argue - how does extra button add a balance? It's just an extra navigation item.

Comment: @Evgeny: removing it would widen the gap between the navigation links and the *Ask a Question* link.

Comment: I'm now translating askbot into russian and actually find badges kind of fun. maybe native language makes a difference. still the tab - i don't know. I am a big fan of minimalism. We've also moved "ask" tab a little to the left, as hiding it doesn't help smaller sites.

Answer (score 1):

We have a tab for `Questions`, `Tags`, `Users`, and `Unanswered`. Why not `Badges`? It falls right in line.

Comment: hey, I've just asked a question. but the case for removal is that badges page is static for the most part and is probably visited not so frequently.