# Enable (up) voting in question lists?

Tags: feature-request, questions, voting

I would like to be able to up vote questions in the question list. (Yes, inspired by Reddit.)

I can think of two situations where this would be handy:

1) **If you see a good question, but don't necessarily want to have to visit the question** (maybe because you don't have time right now or there are 0 answers)

2) **If you see two (or more) good questions, and want to up vote them all before you read a question in it's entirety** (maybe so you don't forget the others after your train of thought gets lost in the one question you read it it's entirety)

Very often I read a question title and think "Yeah, I've wondered that!"

Can you think of more situations where this functionality would be a good thing?

Also, how about down voting? I'm more skeptical about that.

Comment: If someone would like to explain how my question is unclear or not useful, please do so, and I will correct it.

Comment: People simply think that the feature you requested would not be a good idea. That's the way up- and downvotes work here on meta.

Comment: The point is: This is not reddit. Voting is on the quality of the question, not about being interesting only or ranked. And as upvoting means you think the question is good, describtive and interesting, then you upvote. For that you have to read the question as a whole. Reddit is way simpler than that. It’s a link with a title and only ranks on ppls impression on it, whether they find it interesting or not.

Comment: your question is very clear. I don't think we should add such a feature so I downvoted. [See this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42558/why-are-people-downvoting-my-question-on-meta) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work#47635)

Answer (score 18):

If you want to claim that a question is useful and clear, you should at least read it.

Even if the title seems to ask a reasonable question, the body might still be a mess and not what you expected from the title.

Comment: yes, this is precisely why we chose *not* to enable voting from the question list page back in the day.