# Allow voting directly in question lists (with a twist)

Tags: feature-request, voting

We are trying to address the issue [low amount of voting for questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89534/separate-vote-pools-for-questions-and-answers).

reddit, digg and hacker news have a very simple scheme that encourages topic voting. They allow you to vote in the various list pages. Clearly we are [totally against](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79978/enable-up-voting-in-question-lists) voting based on title alone.

One hair-brained scheme I just had would be to allow people to "ajax in" the full question from the various question lists, and then vote right away.

Similar to how [review works](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

Is this a horrible idea? A great idea?

The advantage this has is that you do not lose your place in the list when you are voting on stuff. Disadvantage is that the UI may get a bit more cluttered.

Comment: +1, but clutter has got to be a serious issue now...

Comment: The thought of SO users only having to invest in two lines of text in their question is indeed quite scary.

Why don't you consider just making it easier to vote instead?  Put the controls where they belong, at the *bottom* of the question.  And give me more choice.  Right now I only got 'lower my score by one', ignore, click up.  That's very often 'ignore' right now.  I can easily come up with a number between 1 and 5 to rate a question.

Answer (score 6):

My initial thought is that it wouldn't work.

The advantage seems minimal.  Hitting the back button retains scroll in all modern browsers (Right?  "Most" do.).

The disadvantage seems to be a bigger concern.  There's a lot of UI to bring in.  Would the Related Questions be shown?  Linked Questions?  Would you get one long scroll of the question/answers that pushed everything else down or would you be shown the question and then click next in an ajax'd overlay to cycle through answers?

I completely agree that we want to increase voting - but we don't want to lose the value of what voting (should) means.  Maybe a mock-up can show this would work, but I'm not convinced it is worth it.

Comment: The current UI for review works fine in this regard, the trouble is there is no natural spot for "show more" hence the clutter.

Comment: also regardless of maintaining scroll, all modern browsers have tabs and you can middle/ctrl-click to open questions in a new tab

Comment: @waffles, /review only shows a single post.  Are you picturing this new UI showing just the question or would it include the answers?

Comment: Yes I would imagine it would only bring in the question without the answers AND the only way I could think of this working would be to make the tiny ellipsis (...) a link to bring in the full question

Comment: @waffles, I think I like it even less if it is just the questions that get brought in.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this a horrible idea?

If SO had a Reddit UI, first thing I'd do upon logging in in the morning and opening up my bookmarked /questions page is go down that list and down-vote everything that 1) had a stupid title or 2) didn't say anything interesting in the excerpt. If I still had votes left, I'd maybe open up a few questions and up-vote the answers.

Hmm... I originally intended to imply that this was a horrible idea, but that actually sounds kinda appealing. Opening up questions brings with it the temptation to do things like *edit* and *comment* and maybe even *answer* and those all take time away from voting, with the end result that I hardly vote. This would be peaceful and nice...

Ditch the AJAX thing though. Thing I've always loved about SO is that pages load fast enough I don't *yearn* for AJAX-y partial-load tricks.