# Accepted correction after down-vote will neutralize the down-vote

Tags: feature-request, comments, down-votes

Suppose a person made a comment and a down-vote on another person's question. Why don't we have it so that when the other person makes the correction to his question, that the down vote will then be canceled (neutralized).

Comment: Isn't it up to the person casting the vote to determine if you've actually fixed/corrected the question/answer to sufficient a degree to change their mind?

Comment: *Posts a bad answer, gets a downvote, edits answer to include picture of a unicorn, downvote gets removed automatically.* Bam.

Comment: The another person will have to reply to the person saying what he corrected and asking to remove the downvote. It must never be automatic..

Comment: @RobertMoir, Something like what shadow wizard mention should be good enough.

Comment: Well, that only works if the downvoter left a comment, which will not always be the case.

Comment: @slhck, therefore, I like to have those downvoter to compulsory left a comment.

Comment: I am strongly against that, because it renders the anonymity of voting useless.

Comment: @LarryMorries - [compulsory commenting isn't a popular idea](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87140/down-voters-should-be-forced-to-leave-a-comment). If nothing else it would result in 10 nearly identical comments for 10 downvotes on a bad post.

Comment: @slhck, for the down vote commenting, the person who down vote will not have his/her name appear. This will help to stop a "flame war". I want peace to the whole community, not war!

Comment: @awoodland, as you mention that there will be 10 nearly identical comments, then the reason for all the down vote for this question might also be the same identical reason for the down vote, am I wrong to say that?

Comment: Well, if a question/answer is so bad that it gets more than – let's say – three downvotes, the poster should *probably* read the FAQ again, because clearly, something is wrong.

Comment: @LarryMorries - the down votes on *this* question are slightly different since it's on meta - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42558/why-are-people-downvoting-my-question-on-meta

Comment: @awoodland. Yes, I know that. I just want to make people start using that up-vote. To encourage people to help each other find their answer.

Answer (score 6):

How do you propose to automatically test that the "correction" really did fix the reason the downvote was given?

How exactly would your mechanism work? Should it also cancel out upvotes? After all, the reason an upvote was given might also be destroyed by an edit. Should it remove comments from people who have voted? After all, if I downvote and add a "-1, you've made a mistake *in this part right here*" comment then surely that's confusing if it remains after the edit too.

There are a number of reason edits can happen. 
I might downvote an answer because of its poor overall quality - it might be poorly written AND contain factual errors. We have a lot of people on the site who enjoy editing for clarity and one of them might improve the readability of the answer but not change the problem of it being factually wrong.

Automatic cancellation of downvotes would remove my downvote at this point despite the answer still being factually wrong, and despite that being the main reason I cast a downvote. At this point your idea to automatically remove downvotes becomes dangerous; someone might take the information from that answer and use it. Lets hope the factual issues were not destructive ones eh?

Comment: My objective is simple - to encourage up vote and discourage down vote, am I wrong to have such idea?

Comment: The problem right now is that people just down vote and don't give a good reason. How is that person being down vote going to learn from his/her mistake if no one tell him/her, am I wrong to think in such way?

Comment: @LarryMorries Care to provide any example? Both types of votes should be encouraged, how else are we going to separate the good from the bad?

Comment: @slhck, I can't really give any example as I am not the moderator but my objective is very simple - encourage community to use up vote and discourage using down vote. If they think a question can still improve, they can give comment, edit the question, migrate to the correct appropriate stackexchange site. If they think that a question is totally bad, just use the flagging. I believe that moderators have attain a certain level of high wisdom to allow them to judge which question is really that bad, am I wrong to comment this way?

Comment: @LarryMorries First of all, **don't discourage the downvote**. I repeat myself: How else will you be able to make the system work? Also, moderators don't judge this. Moderators are exception handlers. They will delete / close stuff if the **community** has already decided through normal voting and close-votes that something is not welcome or useful.

Comment: @LarryMorries In addition, all of what you are suggesting (editing, migrating, commenting to improve) is already happening. If you fail to provide an example where this is not the case, what's the point of discussion?

Comment: @slhck, True, all the editing, migrating, commenting to improve is happening but if you look at my account - I never vote down anyone. If that person question is unclear, I give comment. The main objective of this discussion is to educate people to use more up-vote rather than down-vote. If they are unclear, they should always asks the person who post the question.

Comment: @LarryMorries Well, it's what you choose to do. However, if you think something is unclear, you can downvote *and* comment, too. If the OP edits their question/answer accordingly, you can always choose to remove your downvote or even make it an upvote.

Comment: @slhck, I will never ever down-vote anyone in my whole life. If that question is really that bad, I will either give comment to the person who post the question or don't vote at all. At stack exchange sites, the objective should be helping each other to find their answer.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with downvoting in principle; sure it can be mis-used and that's a problem but then that's true of anything. It's use on the main sites for both very poor quality questions and very poor quality answers is to be encouraged. You mention never downvoting people, that's absolutely fine, your choice how to use your votes, as its the choice of others to downvote where appropriate. One thing I would mention is that you talk about helping people find good answers. Totally agree... but perhaps to some of us that includes marking really bad answers down so the good shine out.

Comment: I use downvotes to distinguish between mediocre "didn't quite see the bigger picture" answers and things which are simply incorrect or dangerous. That helps people find good answers in my view.

Comment: @awoodland Exactly. You should also think about the visitors, of which we get plenty.

Comment: @JNK I find your phrase "THOUSANDS OF PEOPLE SMARTER THAN YOU..." a bit offensive. Don't you think that just saying "THOUSANDS OF PEOPLE ..." achieves the same goal?

Comment: @yms - nope.  they are smarter than me, too, if that makes it less "offensive".  I'm not saying that OP is stupid, but based on the fact that he is incapable of searching Meta before making a new post he is no Jon Skeet.

Comment: @JNK, please tell me the link of that exact duplicated question that is same as mime.

Comment: @JNK, also, correct me if I misinterpret the FAQ. It mention that "If your question is about The core Stack Exchange engine that powers all Stack Exchange websites, it is welcome here." so, I assume that my question is asked in the correct site. If this question is duplicated or offensive, the moderators would have closed this question. Am I wrong to say that?

Comment: @LarryMorries - your failure at reading comprehension strikes again.  I didn't say it's an exact dupe, I said the systems in place are in place for a good reason.  The upvote/downvote/anonymous downvote balance has been finely and continuously tuned for years.  I find it offensive that after 3 weeks and not much activity you think you can "fix" it.

Comment: @LarryMorries - I haven't flagged your question as offensive.  I've told you that you are basically asking it in ignorance since you are apparently too busy trying to make changes before understanding how things work.

Comment: @LarryMorries - on the sharepoint site you have asked 31 questions, one answer, and only 15 votes.  I don't think you understand how the network is supposed to work yet.

Comment: @JNK, So, can I say that the down vote mean that how many people disagree with my discussion while the up vote mean that how many people agree with my discussion in this meta stack overflow?

Comment: @LarryMorries yes that is how voting works on meta.  This also has been covered over and over again.

Comment: @JNK, ok, in that case, since so many people disagree with my discussion, I shall delete this discussion as it is not point discussing further.