# Filter inbox notifications for the current site?

Tags: feature-request, notifications, global-inbox

I am currently not signed on many SE sites (but I am planning to). The thing is that the notifications are global from all the sites and it gets messy if you had a lot of activity in a short period of time (from different sites)

Wouldn't it be handy to have a feature to only check for notifications of the current site?. Needless to say this would be optional and turned-off by default.

**Edit:** I am aware that there is an *activity tab*, but it is hard to keep track of what you already read and is really not what I am looking for

Something like:

[image]

Comment: While I dont really agree, I'm not going to downvote, but perhaps you might get more traction if you asked for a new API method to getCommentsBySite, see here http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/usage

Comment: @JeremyThompson I really don't know what is happening, why did the others downvoted or why you were planning to that too? I really want to know what is wrong

Comment: @ajax333221 [Voting is different on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences), people probably don't think the feature you're suggesting is useful.

Comment: nah nah mate, please understand Meta is different - people here downvote not due to a poorly written question they downvote to indicate they disagree, I'll fetch some links to prove it: [Why are people downvoting my question on Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42558/why-are-people-downvoting-my-question-on-meta) Don't take it personally, I can see why you want it but can appreciate the majority doesn't and does mean creating more work for the SO Developers. So unless its a showstopper these little wishlists tend to get downvoted, its just the way it is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Responses" tab on your user page displays the same material, but only for the current site, and it highlights since-last-view items in yellow (and with a number on the tab if you're looking at a different tab). (Of course, this doesn't appear on every page, so it is not strictly what you're asking for.)