# Don't show me notifications or comments from sites I'm logged out of

Tags: feature-request, linked-accounts, global-inbox, logout

I'm taking a break from my most-used SE site for a while, so I've logged myself out, but there are other sites in the network where I'm still interested in reading and possibly contributing. I'm (obviously) logged in to these so that I can interact meaningfully; therefore I get notifications in the hyperglobal unified supercollider inboxadongdong.* The thing is, my accounts are all linked, and I'm getting notifications for the site which I'm logged out of.

I'm not really interested in those right now. To be frank, I *don't want to see them at all*. That's why I *logged out*. Please stop telling me that I just earned a "Nice Answer" badge on a site that I'm trying to avoid. Jokes about Jeff's digital crack are one thing; constantly trying to lure me back is just aggravating.

The inbox should at least not be badged for sites to which I'm not logged in. Preferably the content ("something good happened" notifications and comment responses) should not appear there at all.

Using SE on different computers with different sets of logged-in accounts on each is certainly a point in favor of the current behavior, but it would still be possible to get notifications were this to be changed. If it's not changed, there's no way to *disable* notifications short of account deletion.

---

*Apologies, I forget the exact offical funny name for it.

Comment: +1 for `hyperglobal unified supercollider inboxadongdong`.... plus the request is a good one too

Comment: On the flip side, I use SE from multiple computers and don't always explicitly sign into all of the sites I care about, so I *do* want to see notifications from all my sites.

Comment: @AnnaLear: I see that being useful, but were this to be changed, it would still be possible to enable notifications if you want them by logging in. As it is now, there's no way to _disable_ them short of getting a diamond user to delete my account. It's like I set up mail forwarding in Gmail and now I can't turn it off.

Comment: Related, maybe dupe: [Filter inbox notifications for the current site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126478/filter-inbox-notifications-for-the-current-site)

Comment: I don't stay logged in to all sites on all computers that I use, and I want the notifications to tell me that, say, something's happening on a question I asked three months ago.  I really don't even want them to be queued for my next login; I want them as they happen.  I *certainly* don't want them to be dropped on the floor just because I'm not logged in *at the moment the notification was generated*.  If you want a configuration option, fine, but the behavior you want should be opt-in.

Comment: @MonicaCellio: It _is_ opt-in. I clicked the "log out" link on that account.

Comment: Tying notification to login state is what has to be opt-in. Currently you get notifications regardless; don't break that.  Also, I have never clicked the "log out" link, yet I sometimes find myself logged out anyway.

Comment: @MonicaCellio: The only reason that this proposal would be "breaking" something is that the behavior is already broken. I've closed my mail client so that I can ignore my email for a while, and now my phone buzzes every time I get one, but there's _no way_ for me to turn off my phone. However, I would be satisfied with a "Don't give me notifications" checkbox in each account.

Comment: For *you* it's broken; for others the change in your question would be broken.  If you'd be satisfied with a "don't give me notifications" checkbox, would you update the question with that?  I can't speak for the other downvoters, but I'd remove mine if this were implemented in a way that does no harm to those who want the current behavior to continue.

Comment: @MonicaCellio: I appreciate it, but I'm not really concerned about the downvotes. To my mind, while it'll get me a similar result, a checkbox to turn off notifications is a separate request, and I'll likely post that on its own. Though I recongize that many others may disagree with me, I think this behavior is stupid and should be changed.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Thanks, but not really the same thing. I still want, e.g., Movies.SE notifications when I'm on Cooking, but I don't want notificatons from SO no matter where I am if I'm logged out of that account.

Comment: Related, from the opposite angle: [Inbox notification for different site should log me in](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/189913/335251)