# Log out & forget?

Tags: support, login, linked-accounts, logout

Can a user "log out and forget" being logged in to a SE site so that it doesn't appear on my accounts page nor appears in the daily notification digest?

There are a couple sites that I popped in to that I would rather not be on my various lists.

Comment: cf. [Dont show me notifications or comments from sites I'm logged out of](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157405)

Comment: That's the ticket.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the accounts page lists (linked) *accounts* that you have to choose to create; it does not show sites that you happened to visit while logged in elsewhere.

If you have not voted or posted on a site, then **you can [self-delete your account on that site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account)** (or if you have posted, you can [request a deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/user-deletion)), which will remove the site from your accounts list.

Unlinking accounts without deleting them is not supported, though I imagine in principle you could try to convince the SE team to edit your existing contributions to refer to a new account.

Comment: I didn't think you could get notified unless you posted? So yeah I've posted and don't want anything from those sites anymore for the foreseeable future. So what do I request deletion from those sites? How/where is that?

Comment: Here's a direct link to the [deletion request form](http://stackoverflow.com/help/user-deletion). Remember, this will remove your name from all of your posts on that site, among other things!

Answer (score -4):

The reason that logging in to a SE site determines notifications, is because that is how you register for a site.  Once you're registered for a particular site, then you will be notified from that site.  If you want to not be notified for a site, then never log in, and it won't set up an account for you there.

Comment: OP already has an account; unless you have a time machine you're loaning out, "don't make an account and you won't get notifications" doesn't seem very helpful.

Comment: @Josh, it was a direct answer to his question, and an explanation of why.

Comment: I wish I could downvote this again. Severely unhelpful.

Comment: @monsto, Well hopefully someday you get a better attitude, but I won't let your attitude keep me from trying to help people.