# Is there a way to disable all forms of notification for a specific site?

Tags: support, notifications

I've accumulated a fair amount of rep on one site and don't want to lose that across the network, but also do not really wish to be re-engaged in that site. I was wondering if there was a way to simply disable site-specific notifications from specific sites (up in the notifications area). If not, would this be a valid feature request?

Comment: +1 for feeling sorry for you.

Comment: This might be relevant: [How can I disassociate an account?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109044/how-can-i-disassociate-an-account) (No longer possible, unfortunately).

Comment: What do you mean by *"and don't want to lose that across the network"*? That you still want it to be visible in your flair for example?

Comment: @Bart would rather not lose the rep accumulated ... buuuuuuuut if i must then i must

Comment: Well, if that is all, can you then not add another OpenID to that particular account only and remove the one you use for your other accounts? Or would that not work?

Comment: thanks. i'll give that a shot

Comment: I think that would be a valuable feature.  I occasionally have extended times when my internet access is limited (oh, the horror!), and at those times it would be really helpful if I could temporarily surpress particularly "noisy" sites from my global inbox so I could focus on the most-important sites (like, say, the ones where I'm a moderator).  I don't want to permanently alter those accounts, only shut them up for a week or two.

Comment: @Bart I'm not really sure how to do that, now that I'm trying to actually do it.

Comment: If you go to your account page and then "my logins" you can add another login. Once done you could remove the other one that is shared with all sites. I think that should do the trick, but proceed with caution. ;)

Comment: Related: [Don't show me notifications or comments from sites I'm logged out of](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157405)

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not the answer you were looking for, but if you're desperate it'll do.  I wrote css for the stylish addon (chrome or firefox) that hides notification links to a particular stackexchange.  https://userstyles.org/styles/110509/stack-exchange-notification-hider  In my css you'll have to swap out toxic.stackexchange.com for whichever SE you're trying to ignore.