# Hiding activities from hidden networks

Tags: bug, network-profile, hidden-communities

I hid a couple of Stack Exchange networks from my network profile, yet the activities I have done in those hidden networks (answering questions, gaining badges, meta) are still showing up. I would like to hide activities from networks I have hidden, please.

Or if it *was* a feature, is there a reason why it was suspended/removed?

Comment: This is the correct place to post your request. The hidden communities feature is somewhat limiting right now; currently, hiding a community only makes it more difficult (not impossible) to find (as you have noted).

Comment: The hidden networks feature actually [used to be *less* useful, not more](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253599/hidden-profiles-are-not-hidden-at-all), if you can believe it. So there is some hope that someday it may be able to do the full job we expect of it.

Comment: Very related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277279/top-posts-taken-from-hidden-communities.

Comment: Also related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179434/162102.