# Fixing some drawbacks of the fragmented login system

Tags: feature-request, status-planned, login, user-accounts, top-bar

SE intentionally set up the whole account system so that each site is treated separately. Joining a specific SE site doesn't create an account on any other site. If you want to use multiple SE sites, you have to explicitly create accounts on each one.

This fragmentation has quite a few drawbacks, the main ones I encountered are the following:

- Visting a site where you're not logged in means that you lose your personalized top bar, the most useful navigation mechanism and your notifications. You also see the big banner for new users, and a different frontpage there.
- Anyone using multiple SE sites, especially from multiple computers or devices will see the annoying "you've been automatically logged in" banner very often. That is just an annoying experience

The main reason that accounts are per site, and not SE-wide is that users might not want to be associated with a specific site they never participated in. That is a valid concern, but I don't think it is necessary to fragment the actual login system as far as currently implemented to meet this requirement. Being logged into SE, and being shown as having an account on a specific SE site should be entirely separated concepts.

The way I'd like the login system to work would be the following:

- logging into *any* SE site would log me into *all* my SE sites at once. No more "you've been automatically logged in" banners
- visiting an SE site where I don't have an account would still appear to me as if I was logged in, with my personalized top bar (but "sign up" instead of my user name and avatar), and the frontpage for non-anonymous users.

These changes would hide the more annoying consequences of the fragmented account and login system, but still preserve the benefits. The system encourages me to visit other sites via the hot questions sidebar, eliminating some more friction in using multiple sites would be a good thing in my opinion.

Comment: [Anna Lear](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/155160/anna-lear) is working on this. It's a bit messy, but we'll get there.

Comment: Huh, I did read the post about the new login page, but didn't really read it as addressing my issues. Nice to know that this will be addressed.

Comment: She didn't really mention it except in passing, but the [proposed new UI](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246689/new-year-new-experiment-login-and-signup-ui) is prompted by those deeper changes. We need a unified "Log into Stack Exchange" page as part of making login work everywhere.

Comment: I really don't like this idea, because [I still want the ability to choose which sites I'm engaging with](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157405/). I do, however, realize that I'm in a very small minority.