# Disable notifications from my less-used communities

Tags: support, notifications

I've visited some communities (like Software Recommendations or Meta) only once or twice. I found out a way to remove them from "Your communities" list, but I haven't found how to disable notifications (e.g. reputation for a question upvote). Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Related: [Don't show me notifications or comments from sites I'm logged out of](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157405)

Comment: No, no such way exists in Stack Exchange at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only achieve that by removing your account or disassociating the posts.

Comment: I understand, but these notifications just disturb me when waiting for answers or comments to more serious and important topics. Removing the account is a way I used sometimes before, but I believed there is a better way (disable notifications for these communities, remove parts of my StackExchange accounts in these communities, etc...)

Comment: How do you disassociate a post?

Comment: @Petruza See the [FAQ on dissassociation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96732/269301).