# Possibility to filter global inbox

Tags: feature-request, global-inbox, filtering

Right now it's not possible to filter the global inbox.

It would be cool to be able to filter the recent messages by site, by adding a dropdown with a user's joined sites, allowing them to choose which site to view recent messages for.

I often need to find a recent message on one site but since another post got a ton of comments on another site, it can sometimes be hard.

Comment: Related/near duplicate: [Filter inbox notifications for the current site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126478/1017231)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> allowing them to only see recent messages for that site.

If you're looking for this functionality, you can also navigate to your profile and select the 'Responses' tab (or use this direct link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=responses):

[image]

While this does not show *all* messages corresponding to that site (e.g. notifications about elections are missing, as are messages about active bounties), it does show the most common ones: comments, answers to your questions and edits to your posts.

Comment: Thank you, that's great to know :) It's just a bit of a workaround if I want to find the newest message for another site. Then I have to switch to that site, go to my profile, go to responses and then see the recent responses. It would be a bit easier if I could filter in the global inbox. But again thanks for the tip, it's cool to know!

Comment: Sure, this is just a workaround and your feature request has merit (so +1), though I doubt it will be implemented soon. But one can always hope :)

Comment: Yes! I might end up accepting your answer in 7 days, unless someone implements this 