# Ask again on StackOverflow after no answer was provided on Programmers

Tags: discussion, etiquette

Is it OK to ask on StackOverflow after a question got no answers on Programmers for about 24h? In my opinion the question fits the scope of this site as well.

Comment: [The question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/230413/email-addresses-visible-to-bots-in-public-repositories) wouldn't be on-topic for Stack Overflow, no. And don't create cross-site dupes.

Comment: @downvoter: care to explain what makes this question not suitable for meta? Is it unclear? If you are trying to provide the answer "don't do it" with a down vote, I think you are abusing the down vote button. Just provide an answer!

Comment: [Downvoting is different on meta.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42558/why-are-people-downvoting-my-question-on-meta) Your question is totally on topic, but people are answering your question with "no".

Comment: @DudeOnRock sometimes, downvotes on meta mean disagreement, and people do not have to explain why

Comment: Great, won't ask again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stack Overflow, for the most part, is a place where you can get advice about problems you are having with code you have written.  The question

> Do I have to worry about my email address being picked up by bots when it is in the documentation of code that is in a public repository like GitHub?

doesn't have anything to do with problems you are having with code you have written.

24 hours is not a long time to wait.  If you asked a question like this on any other Internet forum, it might take two to three days to get an answer (if ever).