# A last tribute to the Tilde

Tags: discussion, display-names, fun

Dearly Beloved,

this has been a very sad week for all of us. Our good friend [~quack](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/137184/quack-quixote) has lost what
clearly was a largely important part of his Trilogy life. After a [month-long
struggle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25542/display-names-bugs-no-allowed-cant-reset-unset-kills-profile-copy), he has given in to the inevitable and sent his Tilde to finally rest
in peace.

Having our friend experience this tragedy would be sad enough, but the loss is
even greater: With an ASCII code of 126, the Tilde was the last of the [printable
characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters). The implications of it being no more cannot even be imagined yet.

Thus I ask you all to give a dignified salute to it that "[is colloquially known
as a 'squiggle' by people who do not know its name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde)".

The manner in which you
pay the tribute is of your choice: Be it that you create a Haiku telling its story,
compose a song giving praise to the many wonderful deeds of the Tilde, use your
art skills to design a poster that commemorates the swung dash in all its glory,
write a Greasemonkey script to let the Tilde appear amongst us one more time
– or whatever way you find to let the world know

## ~, you will be missed.

Comment: related (in sadness): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42431/it-is-a-sad-day-on-stack-overflow

Comment: I foresee a pony story...

Comment: Word is he had to give it up because of a certain gem.

Comment: balpha looks on track to claim the first badge in the [always-friday-in-iceland] tag!

Comment: what is navel-gazing?

Comment: @Downvoter: You'll have to ask tvanfosson what exactly he meant, but http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omphaloskepsis gives a hint: "This criticism is also often leveled at professions which are interested in themselves: movies about Hollywood, for example, or television shows about television writers."

Comment: @Dow: *n. Slang*
Excessive introspection, self-absorption, or concentration on a single issue: *"The optimistic trend masks a looming problem, which has sent the travel industry into a renewed bout of navel-gazing"* (Financial Times). http://www.answers.com/topic/navel-gazing

Comment: thank you, something new everyday @bal @voy, meta is like the new-word-a-day toilet paper

Comment: I prefer to believe that **it is truly called a "squiggle"** and only later renamed to "tilde" by people who insist on making up words like "grapheme." (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde)

Comment: @Robert - Thine saying is mayhaps the greatest of the wrongity wrong things thou hast ever uttered.  I salute thee, and dub thee Squigglemaster Prime!

Comment: you are all absolutely, unequivocally, *omphaloskeptically* insane.

Comment: btw, @balpha, *omphaloskeptic* is my new favorite word of the day.  :)

Comment: it's not the last!  *there is another!*  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44265/enable-javascript-bar-blocking-page-header

Comment: @balpha and @quack Quixote: Remember: omphaloskepsis is the only thing that ISN'T easier said than done.

Comment: Where did quack go, anyway?  He's been gone for nearly a year.  Probably being productive, somewhere...

Comment: @balpha I only removed the  "navel-gazing" tag in my edit, no idea how the other text/tag edits occurred. Can you not remove the "navel-gazing" tag? There's only your question which uses it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: @MartijnPieters *blush*, I had no idea. Knew about "thanks" but didn't know it became sentient. sorryx100, comments removed and order restored with little trick. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Back-tick, its brother.
Its wavy nature; its slide
Squiggling thus, tilde.

Comment: Huh. Around here, "squiggling" is three syllables -- skwig'-gəl-ēng -- but now that I think about it, normally a syllable requires a vowel.

Comment: Squig-​​​​gling

Comment: i am so stealing this.  attributed, of course.

Answer (score 35):

```
Console.Write((char)('T' + 'i' - 'l' + 'd' - 'e' + '.'));
```

Comment: How did you find that?

Comment: @Eric: I wrote a program that tested the result of all combinations of addition and subtraction, and as there was no exact match for just Tilde or tilde, I tested some different characters to add to it to get the correct result, and a period worked. :)

Comment: http://dotnetpad.net/ViewPaste/dUng2D9BqE6MGdFMlBhyOg

Comment: That is just awesome.

Answer (score 23):

[image: Memorialized as a cat scratcher -- praise doesn't get any higher than that]

Comment: +1 for an *on-topic* photo that has a cat!

Comment: For the curious, this is my kitty. :) And the scratcher can be bought [here](http://www.petsmart.com/product/index.jsp?productId=3037705).

Comment: Ah! You might've gotten away with it if it hadn't been for that comment, __spammer__!

Answer (score 12):

```
~           ~          ~     ~      ~      ~   ~         ~~~~~~~         ~~~~~~
     ~          ~          ~          ~     ~         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~     ~~~~~~
 ~        ~           ~       ~     ~        ~       ~~~~~~    ~~~~~~   ~~~~~~
     ~         ~     ~        ~       ~     ~   ~   ~~~~~~      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       ~         ~         ~      ~     ~    ~      ~~~~~~         ~~~~~~~
```

Oh tilde,
Speeding into the night,
I hope we meet again soon.

Answer (score 11):

You shall be missed.

## ~

### ~

~

#### ~

<sup>~</sup>
        <sup><sup>~</sup></sup>
             <sup><sup><sup>~</sup></sup></sup>
              <sup><sup><sup><sup>~</sup></sup></sup></sup>

Answer (score 10):

I have visions of tildes flying around, looking for a new user to possess...

[~ http://djtrousdale.com/arts/wp-content/original/2009_08/epuc-tilde.jpg](http://djtrousdale.com/arts/wp-content/original/2009_08/epuc-tilde.jpg)

Comment: The possessive tildes are better than the glow stick tildes.

Comment: Are they legion? I'm sure we can find a heard of pigs...

Comment: ~≈≋ - Oh noes!  They're multiplying!

Comment: Sadly, this image is no longer available at that address. Would you happen to have a copy or to know where it went?

Answer (score 10):

Goodbye %7e, you were ***unique***

[alt text http://www.juanformoso.com.ar/images/unique.jpg](http://www.juanformoso.com.ar/images/unique.jpg)

Comment: Sadly, this image is no longer available at that address. Would you happen to have a copy or to know where it went?

Answer (score 9):

Oh **tilde**, oh squiggle,
oh symbolic **Not**,
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~

you who **approximate** the string
before the knot,
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~

oh curious cat's tail
creeping into the cupboard,
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~

oh deviant dragon's tail
decamping to the den,
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~

you aren't alphanumeric enough
for SOFU.
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~

see you at ***$HOME***.

~$

Answer (score 8):

## *~fin*

Answer (score 4):

I often use the tilde to express "approximately" or "about", as a replacement for `=` when I provide WAGs.

As such, I can only offer my congratulations to quack for having fully realized his true nature, rather than only approximating the quackitude he so fittingly displays.

Your old self will be missed, but we look forward you full antics.

<strike>~quack</strike>

### All hail the real quack!

Answer (score 4):

..
~

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, when I read [Guffa](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44145/a-last-tribute-to-the-tilde/44165#44165)'s answer, this popped into my mind.
<sub>It did get slightly embellished in the telling.</sub>

#### A C-ode to the dead tilde

```
#define puts(in,out) (puts)(in*out)
#define qua int
#define remains(ho) ho[]=#ho
int main () {
    unsigned char *r, e, d=~0, remains(tilde);
    qua puts(const unsigned char, const);
    for (e=-~-~-~-~-d; -~~-e; d=d & ~tilde[e]) e=??--e;
    e[tilde+-~0]=e; *(r= tilde) = e = -d;
    return! puts(++r+1, (~e |- d));
}
```

The code above is actually version 2. Version 1 used `putchar`, but I don't much like the explicit use of 10 — too unportable.

```
#define not(char) int
#define remains(ho) *ho=#ho
#define ressucitate(it,is,friday,there) (put##it -~~0)(there)
int main () {
    not(yet) putchar();
    char r=~0, e=~0, d=~0, remains(tilde);
    for (r=5; r; e=e & ~tilde[d]) r=d=??--r;
    return! putchar(ressucitate(char-,-red,tild-,-e)? 10:10);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My tribute:

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Answer (score 1):

I would offer up the new name of **squiggle quack**.

Answer (score 1):

There once was a tilde from quacktown,
Who danced before names like a king's crown.
      Jeff said "*Forget* it!"
      A forced user edit;
<strike>And far from the DB it was blown.</strike>
And far from SOFU went that clown!

Comment: There once was a man named Bertold # 
Who drank beer when the weather grew cold # 
As he reached for his cup... # 
"NEEEEVER GONNA GIVE YOU UP!!!" # 
Oh, snap! You just got limerickrolled!

Comment: For more limerick fun: http://limerickdb.com/?top150

Comment: -1 for trying to rhyme "blown" with "town" and "crown".... but i'm'a gonna fix that.

Comment: tho you really deserve a downvote for the *limerickroll* ... ouch ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to find the words to the "alt sigma tilde" song (to the tune of Waltzing Matilda) but without success. It would be very appropriate if anyone has a link?