# Enable javascript bar blocking page header

Tags: feature-request, javascript

I use the endless page feature of FastestChrome for Chrome, which allows me to scroll to the end of a page and just keep scrolling to get the next page appearing below it. It works wonders on these pages as well, but when it fetches the next page SO and SU thinks I have javascript turned off and pops that ugly "enable javascript"-bar.

This by itself is no issue, I mean why should you have to fix something my browser extension causes? The problem is just that this bar has its position fixed to the top of the browser window at all times, and ends up blocking the top header, thus hiding both my account links and the search bar.

I tried using a user-CSS to hide the bar, but it shows up nontheless (ignoring !important). So as a last resort, is there some way anything could be done to prevent the noscript bar from hiding those links?

Comment: Well, well, well. Would you tilde that. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44145/a-last-tribute-to-the-tilde