# Flagging profiles

Tags: discussion, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add a flag link on the user's profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39334/add-a-flag-link-on-the-users-profile-page)
>   [What, if anything should one do if a user's “about me” profile section contains extremely inflammatory terms (racist, etc.)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52730/what-if-anything-should-one-do-if-a-users-about-me-profile-section-contains)

Is it possible to flag a profile? If it is not - probably it makes sense to add such feature.

For example: this one contains inappropriate things in about field: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1365061/alex

Comment: Also see: [What, if anything should one do if a user's "about me" profile section contains extremely inflammatory terms (racist, etc.)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52730/what-if-anything-should-one-do-if-a-users-about-me-profile-section-contains) and [How about an Option to Flag Profiles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93411)

Comment: Are you really offended by the use of an expletive? Or is it the bad joke you find more offensive?

Comment: @The Establishment: it's not about this particular example, but about a general possibility of flagging profiles if there is something more serious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer to your question

To flag a user, just flag one of their posts for ♦ attention ("other") and, in the box, mention "Please check the profile of this user, if contains inappropriate content". Usually useful for NFSW gravatars, etc.

### Answer to your situation

I heard somewhere that the bio is fair game--you can post nearly anything there, including expletives. Racism, etc may not be tolerated, though. I've seen profiles basically insulting the whole audience of the site--though brought to the attention of the mods, they may not change it (mods *can* edit bios).

The bio is only visible as a tiny bunch of text when you mouse over the gravatar (for 1k+ users only). I don't think that there ought to be any NFSW issues with tiny-font expletives.

In this particular case, the bio is just repeating a well-worn joke. Harmless, really.

Comment: What if user doesn't have any replies?

Comment: @zerkms: Wait for them to do so--why would someone create an account, fill in the bio and not use it? That's a small use-case, and then you can find a mod in chat directly

Comment: I'm not insisting on the feature :-) Just discussing edge cases

Comment: @zerkms: Edge cases can be handled on a per-case basis. If you need moderator help for such a case, ask at [The Assembly](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2691/the-assembly)

Answer (score 0):

It not possible to direct flag a profile. You can find flag links on questions,answer and comments only.

However you can select any of his question or answer and flag with "Others" option describing the details you are want to say. This will be directly move to the moderator and necessary steps will be taken by moderators.

In case of users haven't asked any question or given any answers, the right place is http://meta.stackoverflow.com to report such cases ( which you have already done ).

Comment: "However you can select any of his question or answer and flag with "Others" option describing the details you are want to say." --- yep, but not a straightforward way of doing that. What if user haven't replied/asked anything yet?

Comment: @zerkms nice point, please see the updation in my answer