# Flag User's About Me

Tags: support, status-completed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What, if anything should one do if a user's “about me” profile section contains extremely inflammatory terms (racist, etc.)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52730/what-if-anything-should-one-do-if-a-users-about-me-profile-section-contains)

https://stackoverflow.com/users/736170/frank-white

> If I see that you have commented "what have you tried?" to people's questions, I will find you and beat your retarded face. Get a life, and stop asking this moronic, pretentious question. You're only doing it because you saw another moron do it first, and it's an obvious attempt to make someone feel stupid. Is your life so pathetic that this makes you feel good about yourself? Perhaps you need to get laid. Or maybe you should just kill yourself.

Not sure what the status quo is about decency in these "comments" but it seems like this would be marked as abusive if it were a comment.

Comment: Just flag one of his contributions to the site with a custom message if you feel there is a need for moderator attention.

Comment: Given that this looks like direct attack on other users I don't think http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117617/153020 applies.

Comment: Have you thought about not making those comments anymore?

Comment: @GEOCHET I don't see how that remotely applies to this case where he's put threats in his user bio

Comment: @Ben: I can't imagine being worried about what other people put in their bios if it doesn't effect me. Something can hardly be a threat if it is not directed at anyone.

Comment: @GEOCHET:  I was really more curious what the community thinks when a user promotes physical violence & suicide as part of the bio.  It wouldn't be tolerated as a comment but this was an obvious gray area.  Should it be brought to the attention of the community?  Do moderators care?

Comment: @Austin: Give me a break. That profile promoted violence and suicide like a condom ad promotes sex.

Comment: I can imagine far more constructive uses for the "About Me" space than this.  If someone needs to rant, they're perfectly free to write a blog.

Comment: Promoting violence and suicide fallaciously is not the issue, it's being maliciously offensive with the intent to intimidate users. You can be a d*** somewhere else.

Comment: So now the administrative privilege of moderation is tied to how people can best use their time or storage...

Comment: That's a straw man.  But, you already knew that.

Comment: He's certainly getting lots of attention now; his rep page is as red as Chinese New Year!

Comment: Yeah, don't do that.  This head-on-a-stick is enough.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The head-on-a-stick?  I don't see Shog9 around here *anywhere*.

Comment: @jadarnel27: Duh, Shog's head is on a platter.

Answer (score -7):

I don't think it is healthy to worry so much about another person's bio.