# Digging Deep into the Profile page - About me section

Tags: discussion, support, profile-page

I have a quick question about profiles or the "about me" section of your profile, I know a lot of people might feel it's nonsense but hey: I respect your opinion so don't brush off, just let me know what you think...

I have seen people link their blogs, facebook, or twitter, etc... - so I want to know how deep can you go with your profile - with *deep* being the definition of **can anything, you put in your profile not seem to look like spam, or self exposure, or abusing the site or violating it??**

What I intend to do after getting a response from you guys is link or add referrals, banners, projects, or other content that tends to only merit me.

By the way, I am a young developer so improvements and progression is what I am yearning for...!

Comment: see also: [Can I link to my Male Enhancement Pills site on my profile?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139190/can-i-link-to-my-male-enhancement-pills-site-on-my-profile)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go for it.

There's no restriction on how self promoting you can be in your About Me.  (We generally cut users a pretty wide berth in that field; the only thing that's frequently moderated there is  content that appears to be offensive to many others).

In fact, that's the *best* place to share projects, blogs, businesses, or other things you want others to know about.

Comment: you made an edit why?

Comment: I edited out some repetitive language in my answer.  You can see the edit history and reasoning by clicking the "edited x minutes ago" link.