# Are users allowed to chose their names with no restriction?

Tags: discussion, display-names

I know that users are allowed what they want in their profile. However, are they allowed to have any name they want?

Are there any restrictions, or does that come under the same "their own choice" section?

Comment: [Here's some guidance](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231362/165581), including a drawing of Zardoz.

Comment: @abbyhairboat https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/286598/sha-t ?