# What is, or isn't, allowed in a profile?

Tags: support, profile-page, terms-of-service

I can't possibly fathom this not being a duplicate, but I looked...

Two straight-forward questions that are extremely similar to each other (hence included in one post).  If they need to be separated that's fine.

**1. What is allowed in a profile picture?**

**2. What is allowed in a profile description?**

Maybe easier to answer in the form of what *isn't* allowed.

The ideal answer would be something referencing a living document.  An answer that doesn't get obsoleted over time and can be referred later, if needed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it acceptable to insult god in a user profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231334/is-it-acceptable-to-insult-god-in-a-user-profile) While the original question is phrased differently, the answer there should cover the general policies for user profiles.

Comment: [What could happen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339106/what-gives-se-the-legal-right-under-the-cc-by-sa-license-to-modify-user-profil#comment1131011_339106) if there's one problem (severe enough), baby and bathwater.

Comment: Bits and pieces of an answer:   https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/335701/282094  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338188/282094  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217778/282094 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1323/flag-abusive-users/1325#comment2050_1355 - [Q*Bert](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22232/282094)

Comment: @Mithical Thanks.  While I did not see it explicitly mentioned in the duplicate question, I presume something that's very critical of StackExchange (the company and sites) is acceptable.  If I'm wrong I want this re-opened.  Assuming it's not directed to an individual, it's not libel, it doesn't link or promote competitors, etc... I did not add this context originally as I didn't want any bias in the answer/duplicate.