# What determines if a user is suspended based on content in the user profile?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, moderation, account-suspension

Recently, it came to my attention that another user was suspended for a Code of Conduct violation for language used within the "about me" section of their profile.

Now there used to be some [leeway on what was allowed in the user profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231362/310650), but also some guidance on general do's and don'ts. I am also sure the new Code of Conduct reinforces this and probably puts some teeth into the policy (although I couldn't quote any of it off the top of my head). So my question isn't so much about the what/why but about the unilateral action taken.

- If offensive content is found in a profile, is it automatic grounds
  for suspension?
- Given moderators' ability to edit user profiles, should the violating content just be removed a private warning be issued to the user instead of a direct suspension?
- Is this assessed on a user by user basis or are there set procedures to follow?

Comment: In 2013, I flagged a user's post for using swear words in their bio, and my flag was declined as "we're more lenient on user profile descriptions".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> If offensive content is found in a profile, is it automatic grounds for suspension?

It depends.

We usually follow the [enforcement section of the code of conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct): warn before suspending. In seriously egregious cases, we can skip the warning step.

Usually, a profile isn't the first place where users start their misconduct, so the majority will probably already have been warned and a moderator will reset the profile + suspend.

> Given moderators' ability to edit user profiles, should the violating content just be removed a private warning be issued to the user instead of a direct suspension?

Again, it depends.

See above. A previous warning doesn't necessarily have to have been for 'offensive profile'. If you were warned in a comment, chat or mod-message to not violate the Code of Conduct and you proceed to do so in your profile, we're not going to warn again.

> Is this assessed on a user by user basis or are there set procedures to follow?

As the above mentioned enforcement section of the Code of Conduct states: "All actions will be taken on a case-by-case basis at the discretion of our moderators."