# A question's timeline should report lock and unlock events

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, timeline

The [timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/67193/timeline) for [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67193/13992) doesn't show the answers being locked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new timeline available to all users now shows these as a history event, but only on the post which actually got locked (in this case, it will be on the answers' timelines). E.g. [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/67194/timeline)