# Capitalizing titles

Tags: discussion, questions, title

This is a really trivial question, but I've seen different conventions and some edits regarding which is correct, so I'm curious:

Should question titles be title-cased or sentence-cased?

Comment: What barbarian uses title casing?

Comment: @random: Uhhh... perhaps moi? \*gulp\*

Comment: @random: [Here's](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/howto-writing-good-titles) an example of another barbarian.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

(IMHO) `sentence casing` is a lot easier to read. On this page to the right is the "Related" questions list and not many of those have `Title Casing` and they are easy to read.

Not sure if it'll stay for long, but for this question title (Which is currently appearing for me) on the right hand side:

> [Should I Edit Question Titles to Accomodate Users with Overzealous Nanny Automata?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92713/should-i-edit-question-titles-to-accomodate-users-with-overzealous-nanny-automata)

is just that much harder to read because of the title casing. Maybe *harder* is not the right word, but it just looks less desirable.

Comment: I hate title casing. If I'm editing a post for other reasons (never just for that though) I'll go in and sentence case it.

Comment: It's weird how it's called **title** casing then, isn't it?

Comment: @Mehrdad, I don't think I'd actually heard the terms Title and Sentence casing before you described them as that!

Comment: @davidsleeps: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Usage

Comment: @Mehrdad, cheers!

Comment: So, is it good practice to edit title cases titles?

Comment: @Kriem Not if that's the only reason to edit the question. But I would certainly make that change if I was also editing the main body of the question.

Answer (score 27):

It's really more a question than a title -- use sentence case.

- Sentence case is more readable, especially when one is looking through a long list of questions.
- Questions may appear in other contexts -- such as a newsletter or search results -- where title case looks awkward, or worse, gives the wrong impression of what content is being linked to.
- Using sentence case encourages one to remember to write a complete, grammatically correct sentence.

Of course, this leaves me wondering if we could call that field something better than "Title" on the "Ask Question" page.  I can't think of anything better, though. :/