# A Question about Mixed Case Titles

Tags: discussion, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Capitalizing titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98066/capitalizing-titles)

Perhaps a trivial issue, but lately I have noticed several questions on SO where authors use mixed case for their titles. Perhaps there is a better term for it, but I mean something like:

"[Inkscape Changing Color of the Whole Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232201/inkscape-changing-color-of-the-whole-object)" instead of "Inkscape changing color of the whole object".

This made me wonder, should we edit this? Do we care? Besides academic papers I never use this kind of formatting myself and don't really see the point for SO questions. In fact, I personally don't like it. I know, there are more important matters to worry about, but I was just wondering and found no related questions here on meta.

Comment: It's Title Case, and we actually had someone a few days ago that was Changing Titles to Title Case, until we told them to stop.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Title Case...d'oh. I could have figured that out myself. And there seems to be a duplicate indeed. Thanks for pointing it out and closing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least they are using *some* capitals.

It's not really a problem, but if you feel inclined, edit it and find something else to improve while you are at it.

As far as what to use when writing your own questions, [this answer on English.StackExchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/6565/602) suggests that consistency is most important when no style guide is in place.  [This answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/6561/602), in the same question, makes an important distinction between *titles* (use title case) and *headings* (use standard case).

Question titles are definitely *headings* in that sense, and most people are going to use standard case, so standard case is a win for consistency, too.

Comment: What about if I'm posting a question? Do I use Title Case or not?

Comment: @John - Added to answer.