# Is it encouraged to edit titles with word casing to sentence casing?

Tags: discussion, edits, title

The conclusion in [this meta SO question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98066/capitalizing-titles) was that sentence casing is preferred. I agree.

**Am I now encouraged to edit titles that use title casing?** (Or no casing, or all caps, etc...)

Comment: Why would you think that?

Comment: Why would I think what?

Comment: "Am I now encouraged to edit titles that use title casing?"

Comment: I would think that if something is regarded as a general rule, then moderation gives us the opportunity to enforce said rule.

Comment: What has changed that makes you think this?

Comment: The fact that sentence casing appears to be the preferred formatting.

Comment: You seem to be polishing finger prints from one window when the next window is broken. Not the best priority!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are encouraged to edit posts that **need** editing.

Ask yourself: does the title really need that edit? Are you adding value to it? Are there other problems with the post that you could fix at the same time? Or is it simply triggering the mild form of OCD that a lot of programmers tend to have?

There are a lot of horrific titles out there. Personally I don't edit them unless it makes the title clearer, less ambiguous, easier to read, corrects typos, etc. All lower case is ugly and you can fix it, but your job will never be finished.

Comment: So you're saying, "feel free to do so if you believe the title becomes clearer to read, but prepare yourself for a never ending quest"? Guilty regarding the OCD by the way, although I honestly believe that proper formatting contributes to quality posts.

Comment: @Kriem Yep, that's what I'm saying. You can certainly set out on a noble quest to correct those titles, but at some stage you have to learn when to just live with it. Your problem is similar to what the grammar nazis face: you have limited amount of time and patience, learn to apply your edits where they really matter. Half the time you can correct those atrocious-all-lower-case-titles but it doesn't make the question any better.

Comment: I guess I'll have to see for myself when my patience runs out.