# Why was my comment edited?

Tags: support, comments, moderation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are expletives allowed on SE sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-allowed-on-se-sites)

For four days, my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6163683/140719) had, after the question mark, something like this: "(To tell him to f**k off might not be appropriate, though.)"
Now it's gone.

*Why did someone edit my comment and remove that?*

Comment: Just for reference, [only moderators can edit comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/459/should-we-be-allowed-to-edit-comments/33939#33939). This was not done by another user.

Comment: I think this leads [down to the old discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24079/is-the-language-brainf-ck-offensive).

Comment: @Cody: That I assumed.

Comment: @sbi: The short answer is that it got flagged as offensive.  Rather than seeing the entire comment removed by further flags, I opted to remove the (parenthetical and unnecessary) expletive.  I don't think my edit changed the *meaning* of your comment.

Comment: @Bill If he's not a mod, he can't edit his comment at this point, no?

Comment: @Anna: Shoot, I thought users could edit their own comments!  (But I verified that this is not the case on a site where I'm not a mod.)  Thanks, I'll edit my comment.

Answer (score 13):

Your comment got edited because profanity is not acceptable regardless of the reason.  See [Are expletives (cursing, swear words or vulgar language) allowed on SE sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-allowed-on-se-sites)

Comment: Where is that ruling? I've used profanity (with good reason) on English.SE. And I've seen profanity on other SE sites, including SO. Don't make up rules.

Comment: You gotta be kidding me. Read that sentence again. It said __"not appropriate"__.

Comment: @sbi, all you have to do is say, "your comment isn't appropriate"

Comment: @TRiG, [I didn't make this up](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-allowed-on-se-sites)

Comment: @Mike: Your comment isn't appropriate. (And now what?)

Comment: @sbi, we disagree :).  Would you like to post evidence for why my comment isn't appropriate?

Comment: @TRiG @sbi there is nothing new here; we try to keep the sites *reasonably* civilised. I wasn't involved, but I fully support the edit.

Comment: @sbi - I'm not sure on the relevance of geography. And I'm not sure of the relevance of instructing someone *to* vs *to not*. It was still unnecessary

Comment: @Bobby: And this sad problem is so bad because so many websites are bending to these silly rules.

Comment: @sbi - would you walk up to a new client and say that? your mother? a random passer-by? Silly rules... that would be what we call "society".

Comment: @Marc, regarding "society"... well said +1

Comment: @sbi, so an old lady can't be a programmer? Just because you don't find a word, or the use of a set of words, offensive, that doesn't mean others won't. You can't know *who* will read content on stackoverflow, it's on the internet thing, so it's available to people of all ages, the world over. It's been pointed out to you that the stackoverflow community don't accept, or appreciate, cussing/swearing, so either stop doing it (no matter how humorously meant!) or expect to have it edited out and the ban hammer eventually drop on you from a great height.

Comment: Methinks it's a little silly to ban so-called expletives simply because they might offend someone. There are lots of other (arguably more effective) ways to offend people in comments, but we don't have any way of banning those. Because they're not words at all, they're phrases and ideas, you know, the things that *actually* have the tendency to harm. Of course, they also have the tendency to be very good and useful; open discourse is something a site like this one is based almost solely around. If @sbi wants to offend people with his word choice, I say let him. And blame him, not the site.

Comment: @Rob: For one, that old lady programming better shouldn't go to a SW conference or visit a programming seminar. Also, you can assume (I've said this before) that there's users here from cultures where women doing sports is considered offensive. Will you bow to them too? (If not, where to draw the line?)

Comment: @Cody, there are plenty of ways to moderate "lots of other (arguably more effective) ways to offend people in comments".  It is part of the "be nice" portion of the FAQ, no?  Someone flags for moderator attention, and a decision can be made

Comment: @Cody: Actually I didn't even want to offend. I'm also not surprised that someone found that offending. (There's always someone.) But I'm shocked that those running the show here are bending to censoring so willingly. From my European POV this all is extremely silly.

Comment: @Mike: But that's just it: I wasn't "not nice" to anybody. The only one who _could_ have been offended would be that silly guy's customer. (And even that would be construed, because I didn't even actually use that phrase, I merely said to not to use it on him.) It was not that I offended someone; ___someone felt offended by me referring to a phrase with an expletive in it___. That's very different from me using the phrase on some SO user.

Comment: @sbi, I'm responding to an atomic comment Cody made, this is not directly related to your question

Comment: Can't we bypass the argument about whether or not certain words offend and whom they *might* offend. It all boils down to the rule set out in the FAQ that expletives are unacceptable. Think of it as an arbitrary rule: we don't know why, we just know we can't do it.

Comment: @pavium: The first thing to find in the FAQ relevant to here: "Be nice. Treat others with the same respect you’d want them to treat you. We’re all here to learn together. Be tolerant of others who may not know everything you know. _Bring your sense of humor._" You then have to scroll to the very bottom to find a link to the madhouse that's meta, where you need to find the FAQ index, where you find under "Other" (the next-to-last entry) a question where expletives are discussed controversially, with a slight bias towards _no_ and Jeff's answer saying _no_ even confuses expletives with cursing.

Comment: IOW: I'm not convinced.