# Why were my edits and flags on posts with offensive words rejected?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, flags, rejected-edits

I flagged some posts which contained offensive words, but my flags were rejected with this comment from a moderator: **"simple edit could do the right job"**.

When I edited those posts, my edit suggestions were rejected without comments from moderator. I just want to know, is there any other way to handle such a posts if flagging and suggested edits both get rejected.

Comment: I noticed all your edits replace the words "stupid" and "idiot" in posts. I hope you're not flagging *those* as offensive words.

Comment: Offensive perhaps not; unproductive, certainly.

Comment: I did flagging near about two month ago. check comment here http://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/1471203?page=5  Question "git-repository-sync-between-computers-when-moving-around". Moderator advised me to just edit the posts. then I realize right process is I should edit the posts and not flag the post. And here both suggested edit http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1592371 and offensive flag http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338713/symfony-is-hallucinating-connection-name/4338789#4338789 got rejected.

Comment: We can't look at your flag summary, @Rais; that's a private page.

Comment: So **you're** the one who flagged those posts. If you want to flag something as offensive, at least flag something that's very obviously intentionally directed at *someone else* - *that* I would consider to be offensive. [Self-deprecation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-deprecation) e.g. "I'm an idiot" on the other hand is *not* offensive.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First, suggested edits should *substantially* improve the post, please don't waste reviewers' time with minor edits.

Now, for the "offensive" part. I went through your [recent suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1471203/real?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) and I have no idea why you thought the use of the words "stupid" and "idiot" was offensive. All your suggestions were removing the words from posts that were saying (more or less): "Stupid me" & "I'm an idiot". I realise that "offensive" is very subjective, but personally I find the phrasing in those posts perfectly acceptable.

In any case:

1. Only flag when you absolutely can't solve the problem yourself (via voting, editing, commenting)
2. Only edit when you are *substantially* improving the post
3. If 1 & 2 aren't applicable, chances are there isn't a problem to begin with or that it's so minor that you shouldn't really be wasting any time on it.

Comment: The people who approved those edits are _stupid idiots_.

Comment: @JoshCaswell That's... true. 9/10 times I'm seeing someone suggesting minor edits en masse, it's because their edits were getting approved at first, essentially telling them "that was a good edit, keep them coming".

Comment: It should be noted that there are more than a few reasonably good cleaning-up-formatting edits by @Real mixed in the list. There are also, however, a few like http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1576995?&_suid=1361768186206012773369811475277 that kind of make the post _worse_.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I thought words like Idiot, Stupid is not acceptable in community, that's why I remove that But you could be true I should leave that offensive words as it is and it should be visible to community. And the people who think the words like stupid and idiot is not right word to be visible to community are stupid idiot.

Comment: @RaisAlam The words "stupid" and "idiot" in the posts you edited were not being used in an offensive manner. No one was calling someone else stupid or an idiot.

Comment: Also, Rais, to build on what Yannis is saying, you can edit and remove these words if you fix *ALL* of the problems with the post. If you also fix spelling errors, grammatical errors, for instance, capitalization, missing commas, adding conjunctions when appropriate, etc, etc, then your edits are likely to be approved. In other words, when you make a suggested edit, the post should no longer need any more edits when you are done. :)

Comment: @RaisAlam You have to see the words in the context they appear. If it was so simple as "idiot is always an offensive word", then the site would have a blocking script in place, as it probably has for the F word etc.

Comment: @Lundin If there was a filter for the F word, [Brainfuck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) developers would have a very hard time using the site... Context is king, even for the F word.

Comment: @Yannis and is there one?!

Comment: @Yannis: well, they did when Jeff was still in charge: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/24206/135736 (see not only his answer, but his edits to just about every other post on the page)