# Profanity in hot questions list

Tags: discussion, hot-questions, offensive, profanity

I don't participate enough in PCG to feel I should have a say in whether that community allows profanity in their question titles, and I'm not particularly interested in opening yet another, "[Is the language “BrainF_ck” offensive?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/24079/2915)" question.

However, the hot questions list appears on all the networks regardless of their own community's support of profanity or not, and I'd like to suggest that [questions with profanity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-cursing-swear-words-or-vulgar-language-allowed-on-se-sites) be disallowed from appearing in the hot questions list.

Today the following question appeared in the list:

[BrainF***edBotsForBattling - A Brainf*** Tournament](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/36645/brainfuckedbotsforbattling-a-brainfuck-tournament)

- Is the general ban on profanity Stack Exchange wide, or does each community set its own standards?
- If it's not Stack Exchange wide, what is the process or response to have such items removed from cross-site exposure, such as the hot list?

Comment: @JanDvorak If you're interested in a discussion on whether the language's name is offensive, and should or shouldn't be used as-is, please go to http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/24079/2915 . This is out of scope for this question.

Comment: For example, Shutterstock doesn't prevent people from using these words, but they do use [a list on github](https://github.com/shutterstock/List-of-Dirty-Naughty-Obscene-and-Otherwise-Bad-Words) to prevent items containing these words from showing up in suggestion/hot/interesting lists - in short, their recommendation engine.  In their words, *"In our case, the question we use is, "What wouldn't we want to suggest that people look at?"*

Comment: We have a blacklist mechanism in place that can be used to prevent certain words or phrases from appearing in the hot list. Creating a meta post or emailing the team would be fine ways to get it modified.

Comment: I just came here to post this, but you beat me to it.

Comment: I'm offended that their list considers "2 girls 1 cup" to be an offensive phrase.

Comment: That list is gold.  acrotomophilia.

Comment: @Won't *I'll take "Things I don't want to Google" for $1,000, Alex.*

Comment: @Won't I am bit surprised there is no "prographilia" term just yet.

Comment: @ShadowWizard there is, it's just not offensive--just boring.

Comment: @AdamDavis Hmm... I'd have great difficulty with that list in my code.  Section [10.5.4 Special Comments](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-137265.html#395) of the Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language would be considered offensive... and no, Java is much less offensive than php.  And I wonder if [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/65467/40980) was a hot question in its day.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There's precious little value and plenty of potential harm from scattering vulgar language across the sidebars of the entire network. Not only does it irritate people, the titles also get indexed in search results as part of the pages they're linked from - we've gotten complaints from folks who found their questions listed in search results for some fairly shocking phrases due to this.

Under normal circumstances, it's best to either close or edit questions that contain vulgar language. However, we do block a range of vulgar terms from appearing in the network-wide "hot" list as a fall-back in cases where there's a dispute or the post is simply overlooked.

This isn't really suitable for Brainfuck questions though. This language *is a legitimate topic* for multiple sites within the network; there have been and will continue to be good questions on the topic that are worth featuring network-wide, and penalizing them purely due to the naming choice of the language designer isn't appropriate.

The [uneasy consensus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24079/is-the-language-brainf-ck-offensive) on Stack Overflow for the past 6 years has been that BF questions are allowed, but the term "Brainfuck" should be munged or edited out of titles. This makes everyone equally unhappy, so I consider it an effective compromise - and I'm making it official: starting today (Nov. 24, 2015), the term "brainfuck" is blacklisted *in titles only* network-wide, with a message explaining why:

[image: Please munge the word "brainfuck" when writing titles, to avoid causing unnecessary blockage from web-sensors.]

Comment: One might want to glance at [the-stick-of-truth](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-stick-of-truth) and consider other title words that you might want to filter.

Comment: @MichaelT whole SE network need to learn [Where to find blood orgy?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/160294/where-to-find-blood-orgy)

Comment: Do questions (which have been removed from the hot questions list) have a chance to get back to the list if they change their title?

Comment: @Cipher Yours is back in the list since you edited the title, so it looks like they do.

Comment: @Geobits ... which perfectly demonstrates the true nature of beeps/asterisks - to hide profanity from robots, not from humans.

Comment: Is [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/36645/brainfedbotsforbattling-a-brainf-tournament) acceptable?

Comment: [This](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/221937) is showing up in the hotlist lately. Not exactly something I'd want a supervisor to see on my screen at work.

Comment: Edit it, @Andrew

Comment: [This](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/52712/brainfk-to-unary-and-back) is another example of a question that showed up in HNQ starting with an uncensored Brainf**k. I've edited the `uc` out now, so this is just to let you know the blacklist doesn't seem to cover this word.

Comment: Fix the filter, don't edit the question titles.

Comment: @Shog9 Another sidebar: apparently it was [auto-tweeted as well](https://twitter.com/StackCodeReview/status/668968234549444608).

Comment: @AdamDavis For some values of "fixed."

Comment: @AdamDavis I think it's partially related to score, but HNQ would make more sense. I've only ever seen questions of mine tweeted once they reach HNQ status.

Comment: @AdamDavis If it's not a violation of the rules to have titles like that, I will most certainly not allow such edits.

Comment: Really, @Mast? I left this blacklist fairly conservative in the hope that in less egregious cases, y'all could work together like adults. But since you prefer to bicker in the comments under my answer, "brainfuck" is now blacklisted in titles everywhere, hot or otherwise.

Comment: That's fixing the wrong filter IMO. Or at least point to a decisive policy stating it is forbidden, nobody wants to violate anything after all. It's simply unclear at this point.

Comment: You'll find the link when you go to edit your question, @Mast.

Comment: @Shog9 With respect, I'm not entirely convinced "Well, now it is blacklisted everywhere, screw you" is the adult response either (nor is [your edit reason](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/103910/4)). While I do think Mast has overblown this quite a bit, his point still stands: The issue is with the filter that prevents profanity in HNQ, not with his question.

Comment: I was asleep when EBrown & Mast got into it with Adam here, @Dan. I try to sleep on a fairly regular basis; I guess you could consider it a flaw in the system. Fortunately, there's a perfectly good work-around for situations where a problem needs a temporary solution until someone wakes up: editing. There's a long tradition of editing titles for this precise reason, but if folks are gonna stonewall that now, then more drastic solutions become necessary. Now... I'm gonna go drink enough coffee to where, if I need to write a more complicated regex, I can at least think about doing so.

Comment: @Shog9 I agree that editing was prudent in this case (and I advised Mast to edit his title, at least until the filter was fixed), again, though, I don't think your response was the one required or entirely appropriate, frankly. Best of luck with the regex.

Comment: I'll make a final decision once I've had breakfast, @Dan - but it's worth noting that the HNQ blacklist was *originally* intended as a fail-safe for questions that *couldn't* be edited or deleted in time. I put this check in place a year ago thinking it'd help, but in hindsight it may have just exacerbated the drama; for whatever reason, BF isn't going away, so a HNQ blacklist just penalizes folks who participate in that topic.

Comment: @Shog9 Unfortunately it will always offend someone. I would be on-board with an HNQ blacklist on it, but one shouldn't be forced to edit the title because of the fact that the name contains a word that some deem offensive. It's a perfectly legitimate word, and it's *not* being used profanely, so it really doesn't deserve an all-out blacklist. Just because *part* of the word can be offensive, doesn't mean the *entire* word is.

Comment: You're describing how the blacklist worked *until today*, @EBrown. See earlier comment about scunthorpe. But clearly this will continue to be a point of unnecessary contention unless the informal rules are codified in... well, code. So, I've done that and I've revised my answer. If you disagree, throw up a "Let's have more Brainfuck in titles" meta request.

Comment: What about the hundreds (thousands?) of existing titles which contain that word? Will they be auto munged somehow?

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's unlikely.  Typically when new rules about titles are made they only apply to new questions and question edits. Since old questions rarely (if ever?) pop up in the hot network questions list, it probably won't be an issue, and thus no effort will be made to go back and alter existing posts. The one nice thing about the new title rule is it also solves the tweeting issue as well.

Comment: I hesitate to bring this up again, but another question appeared in the HNQ and was tweeted, [Generating Вrаinfuсk NOPs](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65925/generating-%D0%92r%D0%B0infu%D1%81k-nops)

Comment: So far as I can tell, they're using extended codes to get around the block.