# Can we have read only access to the HNQ word blocklist?

Tags: support, hot-questions, sidebar, blocklist

As explained in [Profanity in hot questions list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238577/profanity-in-hot-questions-list) there is a blocklist of words that will prevent a question from appearing in the Hot Network Questions sidebar on other Stack Exchange sites.

Can we have knowledge of what these words are, so that we know whether a word appearing on the sidebar is intended to be blocked or not?

Today the following is showing in the sidebar:

[image]

Without knowing which words are blocklisted, it isn't clear whether the English Language and Usage question should appear on the sidebar or not, so it isn't clear whether a bug should be raised.

---

*Note that there is nothing wrong with the question itself or its title. This is only a question of telling whether that title should be shown on the sidebar of other sites. Having knowledge of the blocklist would help with that.*