# How do I delete my account and associated posts on a specific site?

Tags: support, user-accounts, deleted-accounts, lost-reputation

I want to **delete** my account; can anyone help me to delete  my account?

The reason I want to do this is because Stack Overflow reduced my reputation by 500 points in a single day. Now I don't want to participate on this site anymore. So please help me to delete all of my questions and answers.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/can-i-delete-my-account

Comment: Care to give some more information?

Comment: @Hary, you need to remove the space after `@`. A few things to think about. Did you have multiple accounts? Did you have any questions you asked deleted recently?

Comment: @JohnP:) ya i know that .. ya i have 2 acounts ...ya i del some of the questions..

Comment: @hary, if you were using both accounts at the same time, you account may have been merged. Do you have access to both accounts now?

Comment: @Hary did you do cross-voting with your two accounts? i.e. vote for one account's contributions from the other?

Comment: @JohnP :) ya i use 2 acount but at different Browser .. and an differe openid then how it is posible to merge ?

Comment: @pekka:) ya sometime when someone reduces my votes without any reason

Comment: @Hary that is misuse of the voting system, and a gross violation of the site's rules. I that case, you probably have been caught at it, your accounts merged, and all the points gained that way removed - which is exactly as it should be.

Comment: @Hary that's against the sites rules. You can't be surprised when the system merges your accounts after you misuse it. The details of the filter are not public, but it looks at your IP and voting trends to determine whether you're cross voting. Obviously this is negative behavior, because if everybody did it there wouldn't be any point in having a rep system at all.

Comment: @Hary,  please relax.  Take a walk outside, and try to regain some rest within. The past is to learn from. You will see, that if you continue the good work within the accepted rules the reward will be much higher and lasting.

Comment: Should we also delete your sockpuppet, [Stan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/750570/stan)?

Comment: @Hary: Its okay if you run multiple accounts, but not if they vote each other up.

Comment: @Pëkka I would like to delete my questions too as I received no message/notification telling me content is licensed to Stack Exchange after I post it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't delete all of your questions and answers. You've granted us the irrevocable right to display your content on this website. That's the [license you agreed to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18221/who-owns-the-content-i-post/18226#18226) when you joined Stack Overflow.

You can, however, delete your account, causing your contributions to be anonymized. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/can-i-delete-my-account) for details. Basically, modify your profile to say "delete this account", and then flag one of your posts for moderator attention.

As for why your reputation points are being decreased, I suspect that's because one (or more) of your posts were flagged as "spam" by at least 6 other members of the community. Each spam post deletion costs the owning account -100 reputation points.

If you've been posting links back to your personal blog, or mass-posting the same answer to a bunch of different questions, it's a good bet that this is what happened to you. If you stop, the rep-loss will not continue. Unfortunately, there's no way to get back those points, other than by contributing useful content to the community and getting upvotes.

Comment: @Hary: I can't explain why or how others vote. I'm sure at least some of the votes came from the fact that you posted it on the wrong site. It's been migrated to the correct site now. But do note that I've had plenty of questions and answers downvoted. You can't take it personally. It's just a rating system for *content*, not for the contributors.

Comment: @Hary: No, it's very unlikely that the points will be given back.  If mine and Pekka's suspicion that some of your posts were automatically deleted after being flagged as spam, there's no way of getting those points back. If we're wrong and there was actually some horrible error made, I suppose the team would consider giving those points back, but I wouldn't count on it. No, you can't earn 500 points in a day. But you can earn them in a few days. You're still able to post questions and leave comments, so you can still fully participate on the site.

Comment: @Cody Gray:) okies :) now for sometime i just leave from stackoverflow  i comeback in stackoverflow when i m perfect .. after that some one never loses my points .. i realy very hearted ..

Comment: @Hary: I flagged on of the your answer when you directly copied content from another answer on StackOverflow and posted as your own answer. DO NOT COPY PASTE ON S.O.

Comment: @Hary so you've been copy+pasting other people's work, using sock puppets to upvote your own contributions, and are all angry and upset about losing reputation points? Seriously? Maybe you really need to take a break from SO for a while, and rethink your approach.

Comment: @Hary I can't judge on the extent of neither the copy+pasting nor the sock puppet voting, but I think the original question ("Why did I lose so many reputation points?") is sufficiently answered now, and it looks like it was completely your own fault. You can refer to the duplicate link to find out how you can have your account deleted; if you choose to stay, you need to seriously change your behaviour. Both things are deadly sins on SO, for good reason.

Comment: @hary: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joomla Not sure how else to help you.

Comment: @Hary: Here is the link from where you copied answer just for your reference http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6069034/revisions

Comment: @Hary you would get a better response if you posted this in SO.

Comment: "owned by the community" -- wrong. They are owned by the author, licensed to community. IANAL, but answers being anonymized creates awkward licensing situation,  as license  requires attribution.

Comment: @vartec good point - although it probably stands to reason that the act of licensing took place when the user posted the contribution, and anonymization is usually done by own request, so the user should have been aware of the consequences

Comment: @Pekka: yeah, found it. Apparently not a problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18221/who-owns-the-content-i-post -- still, statement "owned by the community" is wrong.

Comment: @vartec it is, I agree.

Comment: @CodyGray You should at least receive a notification/message about that license thing, or the offended user is allowed to sue the Stack Exchange team for sneaking operations (if you understand what I mean).

Comment: @need You do. It's all over the About page, the FAQ pages, etc. etc.

Comment: @CodyGray Unfortunately it is at the **bottom** of the page, whereas it should be at the top. The first thing he sees is a notification "welcoming" him and linking to set an username and an email, or a variance thereof. That should at least include a reference to the FAQ or/and About page, without having the user play "where's Waldo". And no, the **help** dropdown at the top doesn't suggest a possible reference to the licensing terms, but merely help regarding how the site works.

Comment: @need We learned a long time ago that users don't read. The last thing you do, from a UX perspective, is make the sign up process more complicated. You cannot, however, sue because you failed to do your due diligence and read the fine print.

Comment: @needaname You also agree to the [ToS](http://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service) when you create an account. Which states (Section 3) `You agree that all Subscriber Content that You contribute [...] is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Exchange under the Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license. You grant Stack Exchange the [...] right and license to use, copy, cache, publish, display, distribute, modify, create derivative works and store such Subscriber Content [...], even if such Subscriber Content has been contributed and subsequently removed by You.`

Answer (score 8):

A loss of 500 points can have different possible reasons:

- 5 posts of yours were voted by the community as spam.
- Sock puppet account activity was detected, and the upvotes resulting from it removed. (Not saying this is the case, it's just a possible explanation)
- A reputation recalculation took place, accounting for upvotes you received on contributions that have since been deleted;  although it's extremely unlikely to cause such a massive loss.

Comment: @Hary the system will automatically do -100 if  enough people flag a post as spam. Did you post a series of contributions that might be interpreted as spam over the past few days?

Comment: @Hary report for what? Can you show a link?

Comment: @Hary no, I mean in which context did he say he wants to report you

Comment: @Hary: You've been deleting your own upvoted answers all week.  You lost reputation for the deleted posts when an automated recalc process kicked off.  Do you still want to delete your account, or can I just undelete those answers and recalc your rep?