# When a deleted answer get pruned and gone forever?

Tags: support, answers, bounties, auto-delete, ownership

I recently deleted an answer of mine in [a question on Super User](https://superuser.com/q/245102/20634) as the current answer proved mine to be false and, as such, maybe even harmful. Now, **I'd like to [offer @Nathan](https://superuser.com/a/390914/4377) a +50 bounty**, which I can't, because I mischievously could offer the bounty and then undelete my answer (one cannot offer a 50 bounty on a question he/she has an answer).

- Will my deleted answer get auto-pruned?
- ... If not, are moderators able to do it? Ie. would flagging the answer help?
- If even the former fails, could it be possible to [remove my account's connection to the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18226/159930) so I virtually wouldn't have an answer on the question? (On a related note: do I have a *right* to ask/demand this?)

Comment: Your proposed gymnastics seem a bit hinky, and would require developer intervention anyway.  See my answer below.  See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I put a +50 bounty on it myself.

Comment: I certainly can accept this :-) It is the easiest solution, and it did, in fact, cross my mind - but whining for someone to start a bounty on *my* question and then awarding it to the answer *I* would've chosen, doesn't sound as a proper meta question to me. Thanks once more!