# Is it possible to delete my profile along with the things I posted from SO and other SE sites?

Tags: support, user-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Who owns the content I post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18221/158605)
>   [How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account)

I have put really a lot of effort into Stack Overflow and Server Fault and tried to help people. Without expecting anything. I also had a great experience when I myself had a problem and received a lot of help.

However it feels to me as if the community has changed. Especially on Server Fault.

Asking a valid question is more likely to receive humiliating comments rather than helpful answers. Basically you already have to be an expert and know the exact answer to what problem you have to put the question right.

It feels like people and moderators try more to find reasons to close questions than to answer them. I don't want to participate in that community any more.

And, even though I know that this is kind of childish, I don't want my answers and content on it any more.

Can I remove it?

Comment: What are you mad about, specifically? Maybe we can make it better.

Comment: P.s. if it's just [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/457824/) which sparked you desire to leave, perhaps just step back for a while. Let things cool down and come back in a couple of days. That might put the situation in a different light.

Comment: I upvoted this because I agree with your opinion on the way many of the SE communities have been changing. I participate in the sites because I like to help people, and hate seeing so many decent questions getting closed/deleted just because they don't fit some increasingly narrow set of guidelines that are supposed to make define a "good question".

Comment: @jadarnel27 This is not a duplicate of that question. It's not asking how to delete an account, it's asking if you can remove your content along with account deletion :)

Comment: @Rachel You're right, there's probably a better dupe target (but it's still a dupe).

Comment: This, maybe? [Who owns the content I post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18221/who-owns-the-content-i-post)

Comment: @Rachel: Now that question covers it. :)

Comment: @Rachel: I 100% agree with you.

Comment: If you have gripes with a site, it's better to take it up on the site meta before bringing it to MSO. ServerFault and SuperUser has a meta site, as do all other sites in the SE network.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

While I can't comment on your experiences on Server Fault (I don't participate there and perhaps it's something better addressed on their Meta), I do hope you stay around. Having users leave for whatever reason is never a good thing.

That said, no, your content can't be removed. You can have it disassociated from you (which will happen upon account deletion anyway, should you chose to go this route. Do reconsider though). But the content is irrevocably licensed to the site.

Within the [Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal) under subscriber content (section 3) it states:

> You agree that all Subscriber Content that You contribute to the Network is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Exchange under the Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license.

Childishness aside, you have agreed to these terms of service when signing up. So you can't just take "your content" with you as you leave.

Comment: thanks, thats what i wanted to know. thanks for the additional information of the disassociation with the account.