# What to do when OP defaces his question?

Tags: discussion, edits, moderation, vandalism

I've stumbled upon this closed question (reason — too broad): [Big O operation (attempted answer provided)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22434368/big-o-operation). This question seemed really out of Stack Overflow's format to me, and effectively too broad, deserving the -6 votes.

Then, I checked the [recent edits](//stackoverflow.com/posts/22434368/revisions), and saw edit n°3.

The OP edited his question to remove his attempted solution, and now the question seems more like a challenge than a real question with research effort, and even broader.

So, what's the correct behavior here?

- Rollback & explain that the question was better before (though, it was not that good before).
- Push the OP to improve his question through helpful comments.
- Call a moderator, it's out of my scope.

Comment: I would rollback (what was just done by a mod)

Comment: Alright, @BradLarson just saw this :) So that's the way?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This happens to be a user that we've been dealing with for the last few days. They post a question, then immediately deface it once they have an answer. This is a common pattern we've observed with students who want to hide their homework from their teachers and classmates.

Usually, I recommend flagging and letting us know about this when a user has defaced the content of their posts. We might want to look for a pattern of similar behavior. If you have the ability, I also recommend rolling back the edits if they did indeed destroy the original question.

People asking questions can't just take their ball and go home. Questions are being asked not only for the original poster, but for many future visitors to the site.

Comment: So, this is an homework case. Nothing prevents the OP to rollback again, leading to a rollback fight? Do you, diamond moderators, have an "Edit Freezer"?

Comment: @Bigood If you spot an edit/rollback fight, flag. Mods can lock posts and prevent any further nonsense.

Comment: Thank you Brad, I'll act like this in the future.

Comment: Ah, the OP has been banned? I searched through the help center, and I didn't find advices about **not** deleting your question once you have your answer. How could new users know they shouldn't do this?

Comment: @Bigood - This was not their first account, so I removed it. Trust me, the individual behind this has been warned multiple times. As far as documentation, I believe ["Who owns the content I post?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18221/who-owns-the-content-i-post) covers that.

Comment: Should their defaced question be converted an answer to their own post?

Comment: @portforwardpodcast - How? We don't have the ability to do that, nor would we want to have defaced gibberish in an answer.