# Can I copy my answer in Quora to Stack Exchange sites or vice-versa?

Tags: discussion, terms-of-service, quora

I am a member of both Quora and some Stack Exchange sites. Sometimes, I see that the same question is asked in both.

In such cases, is it OK for me to copy posts from Quora to Stack Exchange or vice-versa? Would I be violating any terms of service?

Comment: Why copy posts you can post either the Quora links or SE links,that would not violate any terms

Comment: Ah! I thought posting external links was a bad practice. Isn't it?

Comment: Nope it isn't,Well there is no bad practice or good practice in posting links

Comment: @KarthickS posting only links is bad practice. It's expected that your posts at least summarise the content of the linked posts.

Answer (score 9):

All content on Stack Exchange is licensed CC-BY-SA, so you can post any content from SE on Quora as long as you provide [proper attribution](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/). The Quora ToS grants you [similar rights](https://www.quora.com/How-can-material-on-Quora-be-reused-elsewhere-What-are-the-licensing-terms-What-about-in-the-case-where-a-user-has-selected-the-not-for-reproduction-option) (Quora post) (but not exactly the same).

You remain the owner of your own content ([SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18221/who-owns-the-content-i-post) and Quora are licensees), so of course, you are free to do as you wish with your content.